# How do I check if a directory exists or not in a Bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command, posix

What command checks if a directory exists or not within a Bash shell script?

Answer (score 5975, accepted):

To check if a directory exists:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  echo "$DIRECTORY does exist."
fi
```

To check if a directory does not exist:

```
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  echo "$DIRECTORY does not exist."
fi
```

---

However, as [Jon Ericson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) points out, subsequent commands may not work as intended if you do not take into account that a symbolic link to a directory will also pass this check.
E.g. running this:

```
ln -s "$ACTUAL_DIR" "$SYMLINK"
if [ -d "$SYMLINK" ]; then 
  rmdir "$SYMLINK" 
fi
```

Will produce the error message:

```
rmdir: failed to remove `symlink': Not a directory
```

So symbolic links may have to be treated differently, if subsequent commands expect directories:

```
if [ -d "$LINK_OR_DIR" ]; then 
  if [ -L "$LINK_OR_DIR" ]; then
    # It is a symlink!
    # Symbolic link specific commands go here.
    rm "$LINK_OR_DIR"
  else
    # It's a directory!
    # Directory command goes here.
    rmdir "$LINK_OR_DIR"
  fi
fi
```

---

Take particular note of the double-quotes used to wrap the variables. The reason for this is explained by 8jean [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458/102401).

If the variables contain spaces or other unusual characters it will probably cause the script to fail.

Comment: If you want to play it safe with the GNU tools, use of `--` is highly recommended (end-of-options marker). Otherwise, if your variable contains something that looks like an option, the script'll fail just as with spaces.

Comment: For modern versions of bash, ksh, etc. [...] is a builtin

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: `[ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]` will be true either if `$DIRECTORY` doesn't exist, or if *does* exist but isn't a directory.  Consider something like `if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ] ; then mkdir "$DIRECTORY" ; fi`; this will fail if `"$DIRECTORY"` is a file.  (Of course you should check whether `mkdir` succeeded anyway; there are a number of reasons it can fail.)

Comment: Minor note. In bash, help [, man test (as already noted) and info test (on "Not UNIXes") provide documentation.

Comment: should I use `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that as soon as the check has been performed the situation can have changed already due to other processes.  In many cases it is better to just create or use the directory and react on a failure.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting an error with this:  
    ``if [ -d "$TARGET_DIR/$DATE1" ]; then 
        $RSYNC_PARAMS="$RSYNC_PARAMS --link-dest=$TARGET_DIR/$DATE1"
    fi``

Comment: ``DATE1='date -I -d "1 day ago"'`` ; ``TARGET_DIR="/backup"`` which is a link; ``RSYNC_PARAMS="-azrtplH"``

Comment: Instead of testing for both the directory (`-d`) and the symlink (`-L`), it's easier just to append a slash to the variable, like `if [ -d "${THING:+$THING/}" ]`. A directory won't mind the extra slash. A file will evaluate to false. Empty will remain empty, so false. And a symlink will be resolved to its destination. Of course, it depends on your goal. If you want to *go* there, this is fine. If you want to *delete it*, then the code in this answer is better.

Comment: Using test does NOT work with an unplugged usb stick, since the journaling FS pretends the directory is still there if you already checked it before. I found that in this case checking the exit code of ls was the only way to check reliably if the directory exists:

`if ls "$DIRECTORY"; then echo "dir exists" ; fi`

Comment: Why doesn't this work for relative paths? For example `../../../../../my_dir`.

Comment: Is there any difference between `-L` and `-h`? This website https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions says they're both `True if file exists and is a symbolic link.` So what's the difference?

Comment: The spaces within `[` and `]`, around the `-d` or `! -d` are important, otherwise script will fail with command not found.

Comment: On the vein of teach a man to fish I rarely see anyone suggesting checking `man test` in the comments. Since it describes each test option I would suggest reviewing it as a fast way to determine comparisons you can perform.

Comment: just want to point out if the `$DIRECTORY` is started with `~`, you need `DIRECTORY="${DIRECTORY/#~/$HOME}"`

Answer (score 620):

Always wrap variables in double quotes when referencing them in a Bash script.

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists, even if it contains spaces
fi
```

Kids these days put spaces and lots of other funny characters in their directory names. (Spaces! Back in my day, we didn't have no fancy spaces!)
One day, one of those kids will run your script with `$DIRECTORY` set to `"My M0viez"` and your script will blow up. You don't want that. So use double quotes.

Comment: Another reason to use double quotes is in case $DIRECTORY is not set for some reason.

Comment: "always wrap variables in double quotes...in a bash script." For bash, not technically necessary when using [[...]]; see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS (note: no word splitting): "No filename expansion or word splitting takes place between [[ and ]], but there is parameter expansion and command substitution."

Comment: Directories on Unix/Linux should not have any whitespaces, and subsequently scripts should not be adapted to it. It's bad enough Windows supports it, with all consequences to Windows scripting, but please, for the love of whatever, no need to introduce unnecessary requirements.

Comment: @tvCa I find that users generally prefer to be allowed more flexibility in their directory names rather than being forced to make things easier for developers. (In fact, when dealing with long file names, I find ones without spaces to be a pain as that kills word wrapping even though I myself have suffered in the past from not accounting for paths with spaces in scripts and programs.)

Comment: @JAB I agree, but then again such long directory names cry out for making multiple directories and better sorting / categorizing / organizing files into those.

Comment: This is really a separate question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: Ha. Spaces are just characters that have no glyphs usually. Anyway, you can escape them with a backslash.

Comment: @tvCa Many scripts which were happy in standard *nix environments suddenly find themselves in Windows environments (think cygwin, or git for Windows/Msys2). Or they just are leat loose on Samba shares. It is no coincidence that more and more tools get the option to produce or process NUL terminated file names.

Comment: Another advantage of quoting variables: performance - Bash does not need to attempt word splitting on the contents of the quoted string. (Mostly it is negligable)

Comment: `IFS="\t\n"` helps a lot in shell scripts when dealing with spaces in filenames/dirnames (where \t is an actual tab character and the \n is an actual LF, so this occupies two lines in the script :)

Comment: Your script will blow up with "~/my_dir", no need for crazy kids.

Comment: Spaces in filenames are evil, I'm currently on a mission, with Wowbagger the Infinitely Prolonged, to insult all those who use them :-)

Comment: Spaces in a filename, fine, exclamation marks and ampersands, no problem, but why oh why would anyone feel the need to put a newline in a filename?!

Comment: Unix allowed all characters except NUL and `/` in a file or directory name from the start. That was decades before VFAT arrived.

Answer (score 263):

Note the **-d** test can produce some surprising results:

```
$ ln -s tmp/ t
$ if [ -d t ]; then rmdir t; fi
rmdir: directory "t": Path component not a directory
```

File under: "When is a directory not a directory?"  The answer: "When it's a symlink to a directory."  A slightly more thorough test:

```
if [ -d t ]; then 
   if [ -L t ]; then 
      rm t
   else 
      rmdir t
   fi
fi
```

You can find more information in the Bash manual on [Bash conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) and the [`[` builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b) and the [`[[` compound commmand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b).

Comment: or, assuming it is only necessary to work on directories (and links can be ignored) => `if [ -d tmpdir -a ! -L tmpdir ]; then echo "is directory"; rmdir tmpdir; fi` ... or, for one command that works on both links & dirs: `rm -r tmpdir`

Answer (score 251):

I find the [double-bracket](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) version of `test` makes writing logic tests more natural:

```
if [[ -d "${DIRECTORY}" && ! -L "${DIRECTORY}" ]] ; then
    echo "It's a bona-fide directory"
fi
```

For the meaning of `-L` and other *conditional expressions*, see [*Bash Reference Documentation: 6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).

Comment: for `if [[ -d "$TARFILE" ]]` I'm getting [[: not found

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot and @Hedgehog, are you using bash shell? The double bracket isn't universally supported. Here's a SO answer on that point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts/669486#669486

Comment: And in Busybox ash with default compilation options `[[ ]]` is supported, but doesn't in fact provide any different functionality to `[ ]`. If portability is a concern, stick with `[ ]` and use the necessary workarounds.

Comment: ...if using bash constructs in a shell script, the first line of the script should be: #!/bin/bash (and not #!/bin/sh, ksh, etc)

Comment: When using double square brackets in bash, you do not need to quote the variables.

Comment: The portable Posix version of this answer is `if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ] && ! [ -h "$DIRECTORY ]; then …` (`-L` is deprecated, `-h` is its replacement. Use `-L` if you're on a really ancient Unix system).

Comment: @AdamKatz: `-L` is deprecated? In what system? Neither `help test` in Bash nor the GNU coreutils man page or info page mentions this.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad – deprecated isn't the right word, but the man page for `dash` says "This operator is retained for compatibility with previous versions of this program.  Do not rely on its existence; use `-h` instead."

Comment: @AdamKatz Portability and deprecation of features in dash don't matter since this is about bash.

Answer (score 226):

Shorter form:

```sh
# if $DIR is a directory, then print yes
[ -d "$DIR" ] && echo "Yes"
```

Comment: Does this work like this:  `if $dir is a dir, then echo "yes"`? A bit of explanation would help :)

Comment: `cmd && other` is a common shorthand for `if cmd; then other; fi` -- this works with most programming languages which support Boolean logic, and is known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: The behavior is not the same under `set -e` (which is a [shell programming best practice](https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/)).

Comment: @dolmen the `[ -d "$DIR" ]` is checked (followed by `&& echo Yes`), so I believe `set -e` makes no difference to the script behaviour (i.e if the test fails, the script continues normally).

Comment: @dolmen That's not correct. The behaviour is exactly the same under `set -e`. Except that if _echo_ fails, the script will exit. `[ -d "$DIR" ]` alone (no `&& cmd ...`) will cause the script to exit under `set -e`, if the test fails (ie. the directory does not exist, or `$DIR` exists but is not a directory).

Answer (score 155):

1. A simple script to test if a directory or file is present or not:

   ```
    if [ -d /home/ram/dir ]   # For file "if [ -f /home/rama/file ]"
    then
        echo "dir present"
    else
        echo "dir not present"
    fi
   ```
2. A simple script to check whether the directory is present or not:

   ```
    mkdir tempdir   # If you want to check file use touch instead of mkdir
    ret=$?
    if [ "$ret" == "0" ]
    then
        echo "dir present"
    else
        echo "dir not present"
    fi
   ```

   The above scripts will check if the directory is present or not

   `$?`  if the last command is a success it returns "0", else a non-zero value.
   Suppose `tempdir` is already present. Then `mkdir tempdir` will give an error like below:

   > mkdir: cannot create directory ‘tempdir’: File exists

Comment: The second one would create the directory, if it didn't exist at first. Then it's not idempotent.

Comment: .  The 2nd one seems dangerous. Since it creates the directory, it's not even true anymore that the dir is not present.

Comment: mkdir will also not create the full path (without a param), but the opposite would be even more dangerous, as you are not even able to revert (rm -f) the changes as you don't know which directories it created

Answer (score 146):

To check if a directory exists you can use a simple `if` structure like this:

```
if [ -d directory/path to a directory ] ; then
# Things to do

else #if needed #also: elif [new condition]
# Things to do
fi
```

You can also do it in the negative:

```
if [ ! -d directory/path to a directory ] ; then
# Things to do when not an existing directory
```

**Note**: Be careful. Leave empty spaces on either side of both opening and closing braces.

With the same syntax you can use:

```
-e: any kind of archive

-f: file

-h: symbolic link

-r: readable file

-w: writable file

-x: executable file

-s: file size greater than zero
```

Comment: How is this any better than the accepted answer from 2008, aside from going off-topic with the file switches?

Comment: better, because of [ ! -d directory/path to a directory ]

Answer (score 111):

You can use `test -d` (see `man test`).

> `-d file`       True if file exists and is a directory.

For example:

```
test -d "/etc" && echo Exists || echo Does not exist
```

Note: The `test` command is same as conditional expression `[` (see: `man [`), so it's portable across shell scripts.

> `[` - This is a synonym for the `test` builtin, but the last argument must, be a literal `]`, to match the opening `[`.

For possible options or further help, check:

- `help [`
- `help test`
- `man test` or `man [`

Answer (score 62):

Or for something completely useless:

```
[ -d . ] || echo "No"
```

Comment: It will never print "No". Current directory always exists, unless deleted by another thread or other ways.

Answer (score 61):

Here's a very pragmatic idiom:

```
(cd $dir) || return # Is this a directory,
                    # and do we have access?
```

I typically wrap it in a function:

```
can_use_as_dir() {
    (cd ${1:?pathname expected}) || return
}
```

Or:

```
assert_dir_access() {
    (cd ${1:?pathname expected}) || exit
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that I do not have to think of a good error message.

`cd` will give me a standard one line message to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) already. It will also give more information than I will be able to provide. By performing the `cd` inside a subshell `( ... )`, the command does not affect the current directory of the caller.  If the directory exists, this subshell and the function are just a no-op.

Next is the argument that we pass to `cd`: `${1:?pathname expected}`.  This is a more elaborate form of parameter substitution which is explained in more detail below.

Tl;dr: If the string passed into this function is empty, we again exit from the subshell `( ... )` and return from the function with the given error message.

---

Quoting from the `ksh93` man page:

```
${parameter:?word}
```

> If  `parameter`  is set and is non-null then substitute its value;
>   otherwise, print `word` and exit from the shell (if not interactive).
>   If `word` is omitted then a standard message is printed.

and

> If the colon `:` is omitted from  the  above  expressions,  then  the
>   shell only checks whether parameter is set or not.

The phrasing here is peculiar to the shell documentation, as `word` may refer to any reasonable string, including whitespace.

In this particular case, I know that the standard error message `1: parameter not set` is not sufficient, so I zoom in on the type of value that we expect here - the `pathname` of a directory.

A philosophical note:

The shell is not an object oriented language, so the message says `pathname`, not `directory`. At this level, I'd rather keep it simple - the arguments to a function are just strings.

Comment: This do more than only check for existance: This check for accessibility at your user level. SO question stand for *existance* only. So right answer is `test -d` as @Grundlefleck explained.

Comment: @F.Hauri - He didn't ask for anything more, that's true.  However, I've found that I typically need to know more than that.

Comment: And it never occurred to me that no test can be conclusive, unless it runs as root.  `test -d /unreadable/exists` will fail, even if the argument exists.

Answer (score 42):

```
if [ -d "$Directory" -a -w "$Directory" ]
then
    #Statements
fi
```

The above code checks if the directory exists and if it is writable.

Comment: -a is identical in effect to -e. It has been "deprecated," and its use is discouraged.

Answer (score 34):

### More features using `find`

- Check existence of the folder within sub-directories:

  ```
    found=`find -type d -name "myDirectory"`
    if [ -n "$found" ]
    then
        # The variable 'found' contains the full path where "myDirectory" is.
        # It may contain several lines if there are several folders named "myDirectory".
    fi
  ```
- Check existence of one or several folders based on a pattern within the current directory:

  ```
    found=`find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "my*"`
    if [ -n "$found" ]
    then
        # The variable 'found' contains the full path where folders "my*" have been found.
    fi
  ```
- Both combinations. In the following example, it checks the existence of the folder in the current directory:

  ```
    found=`find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "myDirectory"`
    if [ -n "$found" ]
    then
        # The variable 'found' is not empty => "myDirectory"` exists.
    fi
  ```

Comment: Hi Niel. Your idea may be useful to check the existence of directories depending on a pattern like: `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'pattern'`. Do you mind if I append in your answer this trick? Cheers ;)

Answer (score 31):

```sh
DIRECTORY=/tmp

if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    echo "Exists"
fi
```

**[Try online](https://code.labstack.com/7GMFlEaC)**

Comment: remeber `space` after `[` -> **[` `-d**. i got error because of missing space

Comment: [AGAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script#comment107113517_23077923), this answer was already given in 2008, with more useful explanations. The only new thing here is the online playground.

Answer (score 23):

Actually, you should use several tools to get a bulletproof approach:

```
DIR_PATH=`readlink -f "${the_stuff_you_test}"` # Get rid of symlinks and get abs path
if [[ -d "${DIR_PATH}" ]] ; Then # Now you're testing
    echo "It's a dir";
fi
```

There isn't any need to worry about spaces and special characters as long as you use `"${}"`.

Note that `[[]]` is not as portable as `[]`, but since most people work with modern versions of Bash (since after all, most people don't even work with command line :-p), the benefit is greater than the trouble.

Answer (score 22):

Have you considered just doing whatever you want to do in the `if` rather than looking before you leap?

I.e., if you want to check for the existence of a directory before you enter it, try just doing this:

```
if pushd /path/you/want/to/enter; then
    # Commands you want to run in this directory
    popd
fi
```

If the path you give to `pushd` exists, you'll enter it and it'll exit with `0`, which means the `then` portion of the statement will execute. If it doesn't exist, nothing will happen (other than some output saying the directory doesn't exist, which is probably a helpful side-effect anyways for debugging).

It seems better than this, which requires repeating yourself:

```
if [ -d /path/you/want/to/enter ]; then
    pushd /path/you/want/to/enter
    # Commands you want to run in this directory
    popd
fi
```

The same thing works with `cd`, `mv`, `rm`, etc... if you try them on files that don't exist, they'll exit with an error and print a message saying it doesn't exist, and your `then` block will be skipped. If you try them on files that do exist, the command will execute and exit with a status of `0`, allowing your `then` block to execute.

Comment: pushd is to me the most elegant way of doing this. I was about to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 20):

```
[[ -d "$DIR" && ! -L "$DIR" ]] && echo "It's a directory and not a symbolic link"
```

> N.B: Quoting variables is a good practice.

**Explanation:**

- `-d`: check if it's a directory
- `-L`: check if it's a symbolic link

Comment: An explanation would be in order (by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15015952/edit), not here in comments).

Comment: Quoting variables (even with spaces with paths and metacharacters) is mostly not necessary if you're using Bash's `[[...]]`. The one exception is the RHS of `=`, e.g. `[[ $VAR = "$VAR" ]]`. (This is due to Bash interpreting the RHS as a glob.)

Answer (score 17):

Check if the directory exists, else make one:

```
[ -d "$DIRECTORY" ] || mkdir $DIRECTORY
```

Comment: You could use `mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY"` for the same effect.

Comment: Need double quotes around `$DIRECTORY` in the `mkdir` part as well.  Otherwise, word splitting may result in undesirable results. For example: `dir="a b"; mkdir $dir` will result in two directories `a` and `b` being created, rather than a single `a b` directory.

Answer (score 16):

```
[ -d ~/Desktop/TEMPORAL/ ] && echo "DIRECTORY EXISTS" || echo "DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST"
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order (by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15015952/edit), not here in comments).

Answer (score 16):

To check more than one directory use this code:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY1" ] && [ -d "$DIRECTORY2" ] then
    # Things to do
fi
```

Comment: how can you check that it doesn't exists?

Answer (score 15):

Using the `-e` check will check for files and this includes directories.

```
if [ -e ${FILE_PATH_AND_NAME} ]
then
    echo "The file or directory exists."
fi
```

Answer (score 12):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59871/26510) wrapped up as a shell script

#### Examples

```
$ is_dir ~                           
YES

$ is_dir /tmp                        
YES

$ is_dir ~/bin                       
YES

$ mkdir '/tmp/test me'

$ is_dir '/tmp/test me'
YES

$ is_dir /asdf/asdf                  
NO

# Example of calling it in another script
DIR=~/mydata
if [ $(is_dir $DIR) == "NO" ]
then
  echo "Folder doesnt exist: $DIR";
  exit;
fi
```

#### is_dir

```
function show_help()
{
  IT=$(CAT <<EOF

  usage: DIR
  output: YES or NO, depending on whether or not the directory exists.

  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

DIR=$1
if [ -d $DIR ]; then 
   echo "YES";
   exit;
fi
echo "NO";
```

Answer (score 10):

As per [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s comment:

If you want to create the directory and it does not exist yet, then the simplest technique is to use `mkdir -p` which creates the directory — and any missing directories up the path — and does not fail if the directory already exists, so you can do it all at once with:

```
mkdir -p /some/directory/you/want/to/exist || exit 1
```

Answer (score 10):

One Liner:

```sh
[[ -d $Directory ]] && echo true
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists
fi
```

This is not completely true...

If you want to go to that directory, you also need to have the execute rights on the directory. Maybe you need to have write rights as well.

Therefore:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ] && [ -x "$DIRECTORY" ] ; then
    # ... to go to that directory (even if DIRECTORY is a link)
    cd $DIRECTORY
    pwd
fi
```

---

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ] && [ -w "$DIRECTORY" ] ; then
    # ... to go to that directory and write something there (even if DIRECTORY is a link)
    cd $DIRECTORY
    touch foobar
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

In kind of a [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) form,

```
[ -d "$directory" ] && echo "exist" || echo "not exist"
```

And with [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

```
test -d "$directory" && echo "exist" || echo "not exist"
```

Answer (score 8):

The `ls` command in conjunction with `-l` (long listing) option returns attributes information about files and directories.
In particular the first character of `ls -l` output it is usually a `d` or a `-` (dash). In case of a `d` the one listed is a directory for sure.

The following command in just one line will tell you if the given **`ISDIR`** variable contains a path to a directory or not:

```
[[ $(ls -ld "$ISDIR" | cut -c1) == 'd' ]] &&
    echo "YES, $ISDIR is a directory." || 
    echo "Sorry, $ISDIR is not a directory"
```

Practical usage:

```
    [claudio@nowhere ~]$ ISDIR="$HOME/Music" 
    [claudio@nowhere ~]$ ls -ld "$ISDIR"
    drwxr-xr-x. 2 claudio claudio 4096 Aug 23 00:02 /home/claudio/Music
    [claudio@nowhere ~]$ [[ $(ls -ld "$ISDIR" | cut -c1) == 'd' ]] && 
        echo "YES, $ISDIR is a directory." ||
        echo "Sorry, $ISDIR is not a directory"
    YES, /home/claudio/Music is a directory.

    [claudio@nowhere ~]$ touch "empty file.txt"
    [claudio@nowhere ~]$ ISDIR="$HOME/empty file.txt" 
    [claudio@nowhere ~]$ [[ $(ls -ld "$ISDIR" | cut -c1) == 'd' ]] && 
        echo "YES, $ISDIR is a directory." || 
        echo "Sorry, $ISDIR is not a directoy"
    Sorry, /home/claudio/empty file.txt is not a directory
```

Answer (score 8):

```
file="foo" 
if [[ -e "$file" ]]; then echo "File Exists"; fi;
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order (by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15015952/edit), not here in comments).

Answer (score 7):

There are great solutions out there, but ultimately every script will fail if you're not in the right directory. So code like this:

```
if [ -d "$LINK_OR_DIR" ]; then
if [ -L "$LINK_OR_DIR" ]; then
    # It is a symlink!
    # Symbolic link specific commands go here
    rm "$LINK_OR_DIR"
else
    # It's a directory!
    # Directory command goes here
    rmdir "$LINK_OR_DIR"
fi
fi
```

will execute successfully only if at the moment of execution you're in a directory that has a subdirectory that you happen to check for.

I understand the initial question like this: to verify if a directory exists irrespective of the user's position in the file system. So using the command 'find' might do the trick:

```
dir=" "
echo "Input directory name to search for:"
read dir
find $HOME -name $dir -type d
```

This solution is good because it allows the use of wildcards, a useful feature when searching for files/directories. The only problem is that, if the searched directory doesn't exist, the 'find' command will print nothing to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (not an elegant solution for my taste) and will have nonetheless a zero exit. Maybe someone could improve on this.

Comment: I'd be offended if a program went looking through my entire hard drive to find a directory rather than just politely looking in my current working directory or using the absolute path I give it. What you've suggested might be nice for a tool named `locate` but not nice for anything else...

Answer (score 7):

The below `find` can be used,

```
find . -type d -name dirname -prune -print
```

Answer (score 6):

(1)

```
[ -d Piyush_Drv1 ] && echo ""Exists"" || echo "Not Exists"
```

(2)

```
[ `find . -type d -name Piyush_Drv1 -print | wc -l` -eq 1 ] && echo Exists || echo "Not Exists"
```

(3)

```
[[ -d run_dir  && ! -L run_dir ]] && echo Exists || echo "Not Exists"
```

If an issue is found with one of the approaches provided above:

With the `ls` command; the cases when a directory does not exists - an error message is shown

```
[[ `ls -ld SAMPLE_DIR| grep ^d | wc -l` -eq 1 ]] && echo exists || not exists
```

> -ksh: not: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: What does "above" refer to? The three command lines in this answer or previous answers? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15015952/edit), not here in comments. Thanks in advance.).

Answer (score 6):

Use the `file` program.
Considering all directories are also files in Linux, issuing the following command would suffice:

`file $directory_name`

Checking a nonexistent file: `file blah`

**Output:** `cannot open 'blah' (No such file or directory)`

Checking an existing directory: `file bluh`

**Output:** `bluh: directory`

Comment: Nice idea, however too bad in both cases the file command returns 0 exit code always. Also when the file/directory can not be found :(.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if a directory exists, regardless if it's a real directory or a symlink, use this:

```
ls $DIR
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "Directory $DIR already exists!"
        exit 1;
fi
echo "Directory $DIR does not exist..."
```

Explanation: The "ls" command gives an error "ls: /x: No such file or directory" if the directory or symlink does not exist, and also sets the return code, which you can retrieve via "$?", to non-null (normally "1").
Be sure that you check the return code directly after calling "ls".

Comment: Alternatively you can use this shorter version: `if ! ls $DIR 2>/dev/null; then echo "$DIR does not exist!"; fi`

Comment: ```ls``` returning non-zero DOES NOT mean that the directory exists.
The code should be:
```ls $DIR

RETURN_CODE=$?

if [ "$RETURN_CODE" != "0" ]; then

    echo "Cannot access directory $DIR (does not exist or no permission or something else altogether)!"

    exit $RETURN_CODE;

fi

echo "Directory $DIR already exists..."```

Answer (score 3):

From script file *myScript.sh*:

```
if [ -d /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/Gene\ Directory ]; then
   echo "Directory exists!"
   echo "Great"
fi
```

*Or*

```
if [ -d '/home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/Gene Directory' ]; then
   echo "Directory exists!"
   echo "Great"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

**Git Bash + Dropbox + Windows:**

None of the other solutions worked for my Dropbox folder,
which was weird because I can Git push to a Dropbox symbolic path.

```
#!/bin/bash

dbox="~/Dropbox/"
result=0
prv=$(pwd) && eval "cd $dbox" && result=1 && cd "$prv"
echo $result

read -p "Press Enter To Continue:"
```

You'll probably want to know how to successfully navigate to Dropbox from Bash as well. So here is the script in its entirety.

https://pastebin.com/QF2Exmpn

Comment: `cd -` can simplify this a lot... Or `cd "$OLDPWD"` (Or use a subshell that your script's dir doesn't change, but then you can't set variables)

Comment: `prv=$(pwd) && eval "cd $dbox" && result=1 && cd "$prv"` is probably better-written as `if (cd "$dbox"); then result=1; fi` -- the `(...)` will "undo" the change of directory when it exits the parentheses. Also I would use `eval` only as a last resort, and with apologies in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an alternative to the '[ -d ]' and '[ -h ]' options, you can make use of `stat` to obtain the file type and parse it.

```
#! /bin/bash
MY_DIR=$1
NODE_TYPE=$(stat -c '%F' ${MY_DIR} 2>/dev/null)
case "${NODE_TYPE}" in
        "directory") echo $MY_DIR;;
    "symbolic link") echo $(readlink $MY_DIR);;
                 "") echo "$MY_DIR does not exist";;
                  *) echo "$NODE_TYPE is unsupported";;
esac
exit 0
```

Test data:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ ln -s tmp derp
$ touch a.txt
$ ./dir.sh tmp
tmp
$ ./dir.sh derp
tmp
$ ./dir.sh a.txt
regular file is unsupported
$ ./dir.sh god
god does not exist
```