# How to evaluate a boolean variable in an if block in bash?

Tags: bash

I have defined the following variable:

```
myVar=true
```

now I'd like to run something along the lines of this:

```
if [ myVar ]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

The above code does work, but if I try to set

```
myVar=false
```

it will still output true.
What might be the problem?

edit: I know I can do something of the form

```
if [ "$myVar" = "true" ]; then ...
```

but it is kinda awkward.

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script/21210966#21210966

Answer (score 190, accepted):

bash doesn't know boolean variables, nor does `test` (which is what gets called when you use `[`).

A solution would be:

```
if $myVar ; then ... ; fi
```

because `true` and `false` are commands that return `0` or `1` respectively which is what `if` expects.

Note that the values are "swapped". The command after `if` must return `0` on success while `0` means "false" in most programming languages.

**SECURITY WARNING**: This works because BASH expands the variable, then tries to execute the result as a command! Make sure the variable can't contain malicious code like `rm -rf /`

Comment: Might add not to forget the `; fi` at the end. So it's `if $myVar ; then ... ; fi`

Comment: and `if ! $myVar ; then ... ; fi` gives the converse

Comment: The `case` answer (from @Jens) is safer and doesn't require a fork to test a simple variable.

Answer (score 74):

Note that the `if $myVar; then ... ;fi` construct has a security problem you might want to avoid with

```
case $myvar in
  (true)    echo "is true";;
  (false)   echo "is false";;
  (rm -rf*) echo "I just dodged a bullet";;
esac
```

You might also want to rethink why `if [ "$myvar" = "true" ]` appears awkward to you. It's a shell string comparison that beats possibly forking a process just to obtain an exit status. A fork is a heavy and expensive operation, while a string comparison is dead cheap. Think a few CPU cycles versus several thousand. My `case` solution is also handled without forks.

Comment: `true` and `false` are built-in commands in most shells. Invoking them is unlikely to require a `fork()` call.

Comment: Calling `which true` in bash, zsh, ksh, dash, and fish, it seems that only zsh has `true` and `false` as built-ins. Seems like a sensible thing for shells to implement though!

Comment: don't use `which` -- that only searches the $PATH -- use `type -a true` -- true and false are builtin to bash and ksh and dash