# Bash scripting - Boolean in if block?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, boolean

I tried the code in this SO post - [How to evaluate a boolean variable in an if block in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810709/how-to-evaluate-a-boolean-variable-in-an-if-block-in-bash) and it does not work. It looks like there are no booleans in BASH. Is there a flawless workaround which lets me set and check booleans in BASH ?

My code -

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=true
if [ $flag ]
echo 'True'
#flag=false
#echo 'Now changed to false' 
fi
```

Even if flag=false in line 2, output is still True. Why ?

Comment: Please see Jens answer in the link provided. if $myVar; then ... ;fi logic seems to have a security flaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It evaluates to true because of this part of 'man test' -

```
 [ expression ]
         string        True if string is not the null string.
```

You need to use something like -

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=1
if [ ${flag} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo 'True'
    #flag=0
    #echo 'Now changed to false' 
fi
```

Comment: btw, why did you put flag in {} brackets ? cant we do "$flag" == 1 instead ?

Comment: `${flag}` and `$flag` are the same. You shouldn't use double quotes and `==` here, though, because you want to do a numeric comparison, not a string comparison.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - thanks. but, isn't numeric and string comparison the same thing here ? We are just creating a flag and checking its state.

Comment: @blasto. I use ${} out of habit. It prevents bash from trying to interpret the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 10):

Try without square brackets, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=true
if $flag ; then
   echo 'True'
   #flag=false
   #echo 'Now changed to false' 
fi
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Note also that it's "#!", not "!#", on the first line of a script.

Comment: What is the difference between brackets and no brackets ?

Comment: Without brackets, it attempts to execute the value as a command. It works here because the `true` command returns true, and the `false` command returns false. You can also set `flag="rm -r /*"`, and have the condition delete all your files.

Comment: Please see Jens answer in the link provided. if $myVar; then ... ;fi logic seems to have a security flaw.

Comment: @blasto, whether it's a security issue or not depends on the script and where the value of the variable comes from. It certainly could be a problem sometimes.

Comment: This syntax `if $var; then {...}` is not correct anyway, any empty string `var=""` will incorrectly evaluate to `true`, at least in bash.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting**

To set a bash variable `$subject` to boolean `true` or `false`, use `subject=true` or `subject=false`.
To set a vash variable to null, use `subject=` or `subject=$()` or `unset subject`

**Testing**

The use of single brackets and no brackets is suspicious and I've found several discrepancies in the expected behavior around how empty strings, null values, and integer 0 and 1 are evaluated.

First, defining the correct behavior of a strict boolean test as follows:

- The `if` test for boolean `true` evaluates to **true** *only when the subject is boolean true*. Such a test will evaluate to **false** for any other value, including `1` and any string with value `'true'`
- The `if` test for `false` evaluates to **true** *only when the subject is boolean false*. Such a test will evaluate to **false** for any other value, including `0`, `null`, and an empty string `''`

The correct method to accomplish this is to use double square brackets and explicitly test against `true` or `false` as follows:

```
if [[ ${subject} = true ]]; then { ... } fi  # only if boolean true
if [[ ${subject} = false ]]; then { ... } fi # only if boolean false
```

Note that if you use such a test for boolean true (or false), an `else` block will not only cover the opposite condition, but also the entire set of possible values that are not boolean `false` (or `true`) respectively.