# How are boolean values typically represented in bash, which doesn't support boolean variables?

Tags: bash, sh, zsh

I know that bash doesn't support boolean variables, so how do people typically represent a value that needs to be used later, and that can be truthy or falsey? From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810709/how-to-evaluate-a-boolean-variable-in-an-if-block-in-bash), some ways seem to be calling out to the `true`/`false` programs via a variable, doing string comparison in an if, and using a case statement. Are these what bash programmers commonly use, or are there other methods I'm not considering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I declare and use Boolean variables in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-can-i-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Note that true and false are builtin commands, so there's no performance penalty for using them.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding the ideas in your question:

#### the `true`/`false` commands

```sh
bool=true

if $bool; then echo Y; else echo N; fi   # => Y
```

#### string value

```sh
bool="yes"

if [[ $bool == "yes" ]]; then echo Y; else echo N; fi   # => Y
```

#### string emptiness

```sh
bool=""

if [[ $bool ]]; then echo Y; else echo N; fi   # => N
```

#### zero/non-zero integer

```sh
bool=0

if ((bool)); then echo Y; else echo N; fi   # => N
```

---

There's also a form using the [boolean control operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists):

```sh
((bool)) && echo Y || echo N
```

You have to be a bit careful with `A && B || C` -- C will execute if **either** A **or** B fails.

With `if A; then B; else C; fi` the only time C runs is if A fails, regardless of what happens with B.

Given

```sh
A() { echo A; }
B() { echo B; return 1; }
C() { echo C; }
```

Then

```sh
$ A && B || C
A
B
C
```

```sh
$ if A; then B; else C; fi
A
B
```

Comment: This is a community wiki answer, so feel free to add any other methods.