# Simple condition getting wrong evaluation result in bash

Tags: bash

I have this bash script getting a Boolean parameter, based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810709/how-to-evaluate-a-boolean-variable-in-an-if-block-in-bash)
I created this simple condition, for some reason I am getting false results

```
#!/bin/bash

copyFile() {
    echo "copyFile #Parameter:$1"

    if [ "$1" ]; then
             echo "Parameter is true"
        else
             echo "Parameter is false"
        fi
}



copyFile true
copyFile false
```

execution result:

```
[admin@local_ip_tmp]$ ./test.sh
copyFile #Parameter:true
Parameter is true
copyFile #Parameter:false
Parameter is true
```

The last result should have "Parameter is false" I am not sure what is going on.
What am doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: `false` is just a string and it is not empty

Comment: hmm Thank you! is there a way to force convert it to Boolean?

Comment: Test what you want to test accurately.  Your current test is equivalent to `if [ -n "$1" ]` (if `$1` is not empty).  What are you after?  `if [ "$1" = "true" ]` or `if [ "$1" != "true" ]` or `if [ "$1" = "false" ]` or …

Comment: Remove `[` and `]`.

Comment: @JavaSheriff, personally, I recommend using arithmetic test contexts with integer constants. `if (( $1 )); then ...` will treat `0` as falsey, and all positive integers as truthy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you please post an example? thank you very much!

Comment: @JavaSheriff, what do you mean? That _was_ an example, in my earlier comment. Other than replacing the `...` with actual content of the `then` block, it needs no changes, as long as your `$1` is `0` for false and `1` for true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810777/5625547) on the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810709/how-to-evaluate-a-boolean-variable-in-an-if-block-in-bash) starts with:

> bash doesn't know boolean variables, nor does test

So, as stated in the comments<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678284/simple-condition-getting-wrong-evaluation-result-in-bash#comment119624664_67678284)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678284/simple-condition-getting-wrong-evaluation-result-in-bash#comment119624807_67678284)</sup> `if [ "$1" ];` is evaluated to `if [ -n "$1" ]`, and since `$1` isn't empty, `"Parameter is true"` will be printed.

---

To test if the string `"true"` is given, you can use the following code

```sh
#!/bin/bash

copyFile() {
    echo "copyFile #Parameter:$1"

    if [ "$1" = "true" ]; then
    echo "Parameter is true"
    else
        echo "Parameter is false"
    fi
}

copyFile "true"
copyFile "false"
```

This will produce:

```
copyFile #Parameter:true
Parameter is true
copyFile #Parameter:false
Parameter is false
```

as you can test [on this online demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X1lRPykzTz8JyOHiSs4vqHTLzEnV0FSo5lIAgtTkjHwFJZiwgnJAYlFibmpJapGViqESF1hJZppCtIISkKtgq6BUUlSaqqQQa61QkpGax8UJ0Q7XpJBZrABWATE7pzgVzEBYhKIyLRGoAKI0LZOrFuE6qDVIfIjS//8B).

Comment: `==` should be `=`. As this is it works for bash itself but not for baseline POSIX shells. See [the POSIX standard for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), which doesn't specify `==` at all.