# Operations on boolean variables

Tags: bash, shell, boolean, sh

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script) it has been shown how to use neat boolean variables in bash. Is there a way of performing logic operations with such variables? E.g. how to get this:

```
var1=true
var2=false
# ...do something interesting...
if ! $var1 -a $var2; then     <--- doesn't work correctly
   echo "do sth"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does work:

```
if ! $var1 && $var2; then
   echo "do sth"
fi
```

Maybe somebody can explain why -a and -o operators don't work and &&, ||, ! do?

Comment: -a and -o are operators to the `test` command (which you are not using) from the old Bourne shell, and are obsolete.  && and ! are part of bash syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Okay boys and girls, lesson time.

What's happening when you execute this line?

```
if true ; then echo 1 ; fi
```

What's happening here is that the `if` command is being executed. After that everything that happens is part of the `if` command.

What `if` does is it executes one or more commands (or rather, pipelines) and, if the return code from the last command executed was successful, it executes the commands after `then` until `fi` is reached. If the return code was not successful the `then` part is skipped and execution continues after `fi`.

`if` **takes no switches**, its behavior is not modifiable in anyway.

In the example above the command I told `if` to execute was `true`. `true` is not syntax or a keyword, it's just another command. Try executing it by itself:

```
true
```

It will print nothing, but it set its return code to `0` (aka "true"). You can more clearly see that it is a command by rewriting the above `if` statement like this:

```
if /bin/true ; then echo 1 ; fi
```

Which is entirely equivalent.

Always returning true from a test is not very useful. It is typical to use `if` in conjunction with the `test` command. `test` is sometimes symlinked to or otherwise known as `[`. On your system you probably have a `/bin/[` program, but if you're using `bash` `[` will be a builtin command. `test` is a more complex command than `if` and you can read all about it.

```
help [
man [
```

But for now let us say that `test` performs some tests according to the options you supply and returns with either a successful return code (`0`) or an unsuccessful one. This allows us to say

```
if [ 1 -lt 2 ] ; then echo one is less than two ; fi
```

But again, this is *always* true, so it's not very useful. It would be more useful if `1` and `2` were variables

```
read -p' Enter first number: ' first
read -p' Enter second number: ' second
echo first: $first
echo second: $second
if [ $first -lt $second ] ; then
     echo $first is less than $second
fi
```

Now you can see that `test` is doing its job. Here we are passing `test` four arguments. The second argument is `-lt` which is a switch telling `test` that the first argument and third argument should be tested to see if the first argument is less than the third argument. The fourth argument does nothing but mark the end of the command; when calling `test` as `[` the final argument must always be `]`.

Before the above `if` statement is executed the variables are evaluated. Suppose that I had entered 20 for `first` and 25 for `second`, after evaluation the script will look like this:

```
read -p' Enter first number: ' first
read -p' Enter second number: ' second
echo first: 20
echo second: 25
if [ 20 -lt 25 ] ; then
     echo 20 is less than 25
fi
```

And now you can see that when `test` is executed it will be testing `is 20 less than 25?`, which is true, so `if` will execute the `then` statement.

Bringing it back to the question at hand: What's going on here?

```
var1=true
var2=false

if ! $var1 -a $var2 ; then
    echo $var1 and $var2 are both true
fi
```

When the `if` command is evaluated it will become

```
if ! true -a false ; then
```

This is instructing `if` to execute `true` and passing the arguments `-a false` to the `true` command. Now, `true` doesn't take any switches or arguments, but it also will not produce an error if you supply them without need. This means that it will execute, return success and the `-a false` part will be ignored. The `!` will reverse the success in to a failure and the `then` part will not be executed.

If you were to replace the above with a version calling `test` it would still not work as desired:

```
var1=true
var2=false

if ! [ $var1 -a $var2 ] ; then
    echo $var1 and $var2 are both true
fi
```

Because the `if` line would be evaluated to

```
if ! [ true -a false ; ] then
```

And `test` would see `true` not as a boolean keyword, and not as a command, but as a string. Since a non-empty string is treated as "true" by `test` it will always return success to `if`, even if you had said

```
if ! [ false -a yourmom ] ; then
```

Since both are non-empty strings `-a` tests both as true, returns success which is reversed with `!` and passed to `if`, which does not execute the `then` statement.

If you replace the `test` version with this version

```
if ! $var1 && $var2 ; then
```

Then it will be evaluated in to

```
if ! true && false ; then
```

And will be processed like this: `if` executes `true` which returns success; which is reversed by `!`; because the return code of the first command was failure the `&&` statement short circuits and `false` never gets executed. Because the final command executed returned a failure, failure is passed back to `if` which does not execute the `then` clause.

I  hope this is all clear.

It is perhaps worth pointing out that you can use constructs like this:

```
! false && true && echo 1
```

Which does not use `if` but still checks return codes, because that is what `&&` and `||` are for.

There is kind of a black art to using `test` without making any mistakes. In general, when using `bash`, the newer `[[` command should be used instead because it is more powerful and does away with lots of gotchas which must, for compatibility reasons, be kept in `[`.

Since the original poster did not supply a realistic example of what he's trying to accomplish it's hard to give any specific advice as to the best solution. Hopefully this has been sufficiently helpful that he can now figure out the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed here two different syntaxes.

This will work:

```
if ! [ 1 -a 2 ]; then
   echo "do sth"
fi
```

Note brackets around the expressions.

You need the `test` command (`[` in newer syntax) to use these keys (`-a`, `-o` and so on).

But `test` does nut run commands itself.
If you want to check exit codes of commands you must not use `test`.

Comment: No, `[` and `test` became available more or less concurrently and are both very old. The "newer" conditional construct is `[[` which Bash, ksh and zsh support. `test` doesn't run commands, but `if` does (since `test`, `[` and `[[` are commands rather than syntax elements).

Comment: @Dennis: I mean you can't write `if [ $var1 -a $var2 ]` because `test` doesn't run commands.