# shell script test command confusion

Tags: shell

I am having some trouble understand `test` command in shell scripting.

From this piece of code here:

```
if [ ! "$n_trig" -a "$i_trig" ]
then 
    usage
    echo "Required options -n and -i are not present"
    exit 1
fi
```

I would expect the command list in the if statement to be executed since `n_trip` and `i_trig` are both set to false.. However it does not execute. If I remove `!` it does. I don't understand why.

Here is the output of `sh -x ./script`:

```
+ n_trig=false
+ i_trig=false
+ p_trig=false
+ getopts n:i:p: opt
+ '[' '!' false -a false ']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: [How to declare and use boolean variables in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script)

Booleans in shell scripts are not super reliable as there is lots of variation between different shells.

That said your test is not correct since the ! only applies to the first value

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ true != "$n_trig" ]  && [  true !=  "$i_trig" ]
then
    usage
    echo "Required options -n and -i are not present"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It's not so much that boolean variables are not reliable; it's that they don't exist. Shell scripts have exactly one type, strings, which is why you need, for example, separate operators for string ("=") and integer ("-eq") comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` operator is just being applied only to the sub-expression `"$n_trig"`, not to the entire expression. You can either use it outside the test, as part of the `if` command:

```
if ! [ "$n_trig" -a "$i_trig" ]
```

or you can use parentheses inside the `test` command:

```
if [ ! \( "$n_trig" -a "$i_trig" \) ]
```

Also, `test "$var"` just tests whether the variable is not empty, it doesn't treat the value `false` as false. If a variable can contain `true` or `false`, you should do:

```
if ! [ "$n_trig" != true -a "$i_trig" != true ]
```