# booleanParam in jenkins dsl

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins groovy script like this:

```
    freeStyleJob(“test”) {
        properties { githubProjectUrl(‘…’) }
        description(‘’’job description’’’.stripMargin('|'))

        logRotator{ numToKeep(100) }

        parameters {
            stringParam(’STRINGP1’, "", “STRINGP1 description”)
            stringParam('STRINGP2’, "", “StringP2 description”)
            booleanParam(‘b1’, false)
            booleanParam(‘b2’, false)
            booleanParam(‘b3’, false)
            stringParam("EMAIL_LIST", "", "Emails")
        }

        scm {
            github(‘repo’, '${STRINGP1}', 'git', ‘giturl’)
        }

        steps {
            shell '''|#!/bin/bash
                |ARGS=""
                |fi
                |if [[ ‘${b1}’ ]]; then
                |   ARGS=$ARGS" —-p b1”
                |fi
                |if [[ ‘${b2}’ ]]; then
                |   OS_ARGS=$ARGS" —-p b2”
                |fi
                |if [[ ‘${b3}’ ]]; then
                |   ARGS=$ARGS" —-p b3”
                |fi                
                |echo ${ARGS}'''.stripMargin('|')

        }

        publishers {
            archiveArtifacts {
                pattern(‘pattern’)
            }

            extendedEmail {
                ....
                }
            }

        }

    ....
  }
```

After the creation of job no matter whether user checks or unchecks the boolean parameter in the UI, the value for ARGS would be always "--p b1 ---p b2 --p b3". It means that the three if that exist in the shell script will be always evaluated to true. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 11):

Parameters are available from both `env` and `params`. When you access them as `$b1` you are getting them from `env`, not `params`.

All *environmental variables* are strings by their nature so when you access params as environmental variables, they are *always* strings.

If you want to access them as they are typed, use `params`:

```
script {
  assert env.b1 instanceof String
  assert params.b1 instanceof Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 5):

At least for Pipeline scripts, Boolean parameter are in reality strings. So I do the following:

```
parameterAsBoolean = (MY_PARAMETER == "true")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your shell script standalone? Just to make sure it acts as you want?

I think your syntax might be wrong, you values will always be valid since they exist, please check this one as reference:
[How to declare and use boolean variables in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script)