# bash if statement, toggle

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

This doesn't work, and every time executes the else clause:

```
state=false
function toggle {
  if [ ! $state ]
  then
    echo first
    state=true
  else
    echo second
    state=false
  fi
}
```

I'd expect calling `toggle` multiple times would have alternating output between "first" and "second", but instead I only get "second"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` doesn't use the strings `true` and `false` for boolean values. `test` treats any non-empty string as true, and an empty string as false.

You need to perform explicit comparisons:

```
state=false
function toggle {
  if [ "$state" = false ]
  then
    echo first
    state=true
  else
    echo second
    state=false
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `true` and `false` are, in your case, just strings, which evaluate to the logical true.

So regardless on whether state contains the word `true` or `false`, `[ ! $state ]` will always revert to the logical `false` -- triggering your `else` clause.

Since you are already using `true` and `false`, there is something you can do: Both `true` and `false` are valid shell commands that do nothing but return an error code of 0 and 1, respectively. Since `if` basically evaluates a command (look it up, `[` is an executable) and uses their error code, you could do something like this:

```
if $state;
```

`$state` would be either `false` or `true`, which would then be executed by `if`, and, depending on the error code, select which specific code block of the `if ... else ... fi` block would be executed.

Comment: `-eq` is for numbers, `=` is for strings.

Comment: You're right, I made something completely different anyway ;)

Comment: While this works, I suggest you make it clearer that this _only_ works as intended with `$state` values of `false` and `true`, and that the approach relies on executing the variable value - whatever it happens to be - _as a command_.

Comment: I think I made it clearer. The solution of @Barmar probably still is much easier to understand, so I've also upvoted his.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where it went, but my favourite answer seems to have disappeared.

```
state=
function toggle {
  if [ ! $state ]
  then
    echo first
    state=true
  else
    echo second
    state=
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BASH 4+ version as a function :

```
# -- Toggle between TRUE and FALSE with a variable every time called --
# Globals: None
# Arguments: boolean (pass in previous)
# Returns: boolean (switched value)
# --
toggle_true_false() {
    toggle="${1}"
    if [[ -z ${toggle} ]] || [[ ${toggle} = false ]] ; then
        toggle=true
    else
        toggle=false
    fi
    echo ${toggle}
}
```

How to use it :

```
local toggle
while [[ 1 ]] ; do
    toggle=$(toggle_true_false ${toggle})
    if ${toggle} ;then echo "value is TRUE" ;else echo "value is FALSE" ;fi
done
```

Basically we declare a variable and then call the function that will reverse it's value and store it back in the variable. Then you can call some other command based on the value of this toggle value..

Output:

```
value is TRUE
value is FALSE
value is TRUE
value is FALSE
value is TRUE
value is FALSE
value is TRUE
....
```

Further reading : Dealing with boolean: [How to declare and use boolean variables in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script) and how to use functions: [Passing parameters to a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function)