# Boolean variables in a shell script

Tags: shell, boolean, logical-operators

I follow this post
[How to declare and use boolean variables in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script)

and developed a simple shell script

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                   
a=false
if [[ $a ]];
then
    echo "a is true"
else
    echo "a is false"
fi
```

The output is

```
a is true
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `if [[ $a ]]` is not one of the options listed in any of the answers of the question you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work since `[[` only tests if the variable is empty. 
You need write:

```
if [[ $a = true ]];
```

instead of only

```
if [[ $a ]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the value equals `true`, not just whether the variable is set or not. Try the following:

```
if [[ $a = true ]];
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Note that `true` and `false` are actually builtin *commands* in bash, so you can omit the conditional brackets and just do:</strike>

```
if $a;
```

*Update:* after reading [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210966/7552), I rescind this advice.

---

The reason `if [[ $a ]]` doesn't work like you expect is that when then `[[` command receives only a single argument (aside from the closing `]]`), the return value is success if the argument is non-empty. Clearly the string "false" is not the empty string. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions