# shell command not working in if/else statement

Tags: shell

i'm new to shell script.
i wrote a test script that encode/decode plain text to base64 string.
but it does not work what i thought. i want to decode base64 encoded string to plain text if ENCODING var is false.

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENCODING=false
INPUT_STRING=dGVzdF9zdHJpbmcK

if [ $ENCODING ]; then
    echo "$INPUT_STRING" | base64
else
    echo "$INPUT_STRING" | base64 --decode
fi
```

output of script:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-252-34-162 ~]$ ./test.sh
ZEdWemRGOXpkSEpwYm1jSwo=
```

the 'else' statement not working. but follow command works fine

```
echo "$INPUT_STRING" | base64 --decode
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare and use boolean variables in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-to-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-shell-script)

Comment: @a611155 : Note that `[ false ]` evaluates to true, in the same way that `[ foobarbaz ]` evaluates to true. From the viewpoint of the `[` command, any non-empty string is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing your variable as strings works. I.e:

```
if [ "$ENCODING" == "false" ];
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works like magic.You saved me a lot of time.
Why didn't the code work? 
Can you give me a keyword I can search for or a link to a referenced document?

Comment: In http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html you can find the basics of *if* construct and its operators.