# bash + how to validate if string is boolean

Tags: linux, bash, boolean

in my bash script I did the following syntax in order to verify if $Val is boolean

```
if [[ $Val != True ]] && [[ $Val != False ]];then
    echo "sorry but Val isn't a boolean"
    exit 1
else
    echo "good state $Val is a boolean"
fi
```

any other idea how to do it more elegant?

so if $Val is `True` or `False`  , then its good state
if not then we do `exit 1`

when I use `"[[ $Val != @(True|False) ]]"` ,

then in my python charm editor I get:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I declare and use Boolean variables in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-can-i-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953646/how-can-i-declare-and-use-boolean-variables-in-a-shell-script .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard shell `case` construct may be used for that. It can match a given string against one or more shell patterns:

```
case $Val in
  True | False) echo "good state $Val is a boolean";;
  *) echo "sorry but Val isn't a boolean"; exit 1;;
esac >&2
```

Alternative patterns for the same case are separated by `|`. Unquoted leading or trailing blanks in the pattern are ignored.

The list for a case may be empty. So if you just wanted to exit after failing to match "True" or "False", you can do that:

```
case $Val in
  True | False) ;;
  *) echo "sorry but Val isn't a boolean"; exit 1;;
esac >&2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an extended glob:

```
if [[ $Val != @(True|False) ]]; then
  echo "sorry but Val isn't a boolean" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# continue with good value of Val
```

Older versions of `bash` may require you to explicitly enable extended globs with `shopt -s extglob` first, but newer versions temporarily enable the option inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: from some unclear reason I get error in my python charm GUI with red line under $val

Comment: Because PyCharm is probably trying to parse this as Python, not shell.

Comment: as you know python charm can use also for shell script or bash , all my bash script are edit correctly

Comment: I don't know; I don't use PyCharm, and nothing I've ever read about it hear makes me interested in trying it out. But whether the *editor* understands the syntax of the file you are editing is independent of whether you can execute it with the appropriate interpreter.