# What is the difference between double and single square brackets [ and [[ as well as equal signs = and ==?

Tags: string, bash, testing, comparison

I cannot find the difference between:

```
[ $foo = b* ]
[ $foo == b* ]

[[ $foo = b* ]]
[[ $foo == b* ]]
```

Comment: do some reading at [tdlp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) then come back here if there is something you don't understand. This is also a very good [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Difference between `[]` and `[[]]` check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash)

Difference between `=` and `==`

`=` is assignment operator

`==` equality check operator OR conditional operator

Comment: Not quite.  In both `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`, `=` is a string equality comparison not an assignment.  `[[ ]]` and some implementations of `[ ]` also accept `==` as a synonym. (p.s. I'm not sure what you mean by "conditional operator".)

Answer (score 0):

`[]` vs `[[ ]]` in general was covered at [Is [[ ]] preferable over [ ] in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts) so let's not touch it.

`=` vs `==`:

**Inside [ ]**

- `=` is POSIX and [checks if strings are equal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)
- `==` is a Bash defined alias to it, see `man bash`.

So only use `=` as it is both more portable and shorter.

**Inside [[ ]]**

`[[ ]]` is not POSIX, so we refer only to `man bash`.

It says under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` that `=` and `==` are the same inside `[[ ]]` and that both do pattern matching as described at "Compound Commands".

Then "Compound Commands" is the same pattern used for glob expansion, e.g.:

```
[[ 'abcde' = ?b[cC]* ]] && echo true
```

possibly with `extglob` extensions.

Note that you must *not* quote the pattern: it will not glob expand to files as usual. If you quote it, you lose the pattern matching magic and get literal characters.