# "[ ]" vs. "[[ ]]" in Bash shell

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting, if-statement

This may be answered already but I am going to ask it anyways. I have two versions of a script (`comp.sh`)-

```
#!/bin/sh
export tDay=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
newfile="filename_$tDay"
filename="filename_20120821100002.csv"
echo $newfile $filename
if [ $filename = *$newfile* ]
then
  echo "Matched"
else
  echo "Not Matched!"
fi

Output:
$ ./comp.sh
filename_20120821 filename_20120821100002.csv
Not Matched!
```

And

```
#!/bin/sh
export tDay=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
newfile="filename_$tDay"
filename="filename_20120821100002.csv"
echo $newfile $filename
if [[ $filename = *$newfile* ]]
then
  echo "Matched"
else
  echo "Not Matched!"
fi

$ comp.sh
filename_20120821 filename_20120821100002.csv
Matched
```

Could someone explain me Why the difference?

Also - under what circumstances should `[ ]` be used vs. `[[ ]]` and vice versa?

Comment: This question is similar and has a good answer that points to great documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`test`'s string equality operator doesn't do globs.

```
$ [ abc = *bc ] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ abc = *bc ]] ; echo $?
0
```

Comment: I can see that. But why, can you elaborate why `[ ]` vs. `[[ ]]` makes the difference?

Comment: No, I can't. There are a great many things most people don't know, simply because the decision-making process that brought those things about was opaque.

Comment: Ok, so `[ ]` apparently was(is) a program `test`?

Comment: @Annjawn: It is available as both a separate program and as a bash builtin.

Comment: Confusing! so is that the reason one should select `[[ ]]` over `[ ]`?

Comment: @pst: From `help [[`: "When the `==' and `!=' operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is used as a pattern and pattern matching is performed." where "pattern" means "glob".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ahh, the double-`==` threw me off. That makes sense now, since `==` and `=` are (implicitly) stated to be aliases in the operator section ..

Comment: @Annjawn: No. One should use `[` only if `[[` is not available or does not follow the desired behavior.

Comment: @Annjawn- On most systems, [`[` is an alias for the command `test`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html), and `]` is typically aliased to nothing (it's only there because matching braces are easier to read). `[[` is a keyword, not a command.

Answer (score 20):

`[[` is a bash built-in, and cannot be used in a `#!/bin/sh` script. You'll want to read the [Conditional Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) section of the bash manual to learn the capabilities of `[[`. The major benefits that spring to mind:

- `==` and `!=` perform pattern matching, so the right-hand side can be a glob pattern
- `=~` performs regular expression matching. Captured groups are stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array.
- boolean operators `&&` and `||`
- parenthèses for grouping of expressions.
- no word splitting, so it's not strictly necessary to quote your variables.

The major drawback: your script is now bash-specific.

Comment: isn't `[[` a bash keyword?

Comment: Yes. The fact that it's a keyword and not a command is what allows bash to have special parsing rules (such as no word splitting)

Answer (score 4):

`Also - under what circumstances should [ ] be used vs. [[ ]] and vice versa?`

It depends.  If you care about portability and want your shell scripts to run on a variety of shells, then you should never use `[[`.  If you want the features provided by `[[` on some shells, you should use `[[` when you want those features.  Personally, I never use `[[` because portability is important to me.

Comment: But lets say I don't want to use `[[ ]]` but also want to do substring comparison as in my code above, how'd I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for `if echo "$filename" | grep -qF "$newfile"; then ...` ?

Comment: something like that but without `grep`. So if i understand this, this is the only way to make my code compatible on multiple shell types and avoid using `[[`.

Comment: its not the only way, you can also do `case "$filename" in  *$newfile* ) ... `

Comment: so do you suggest using these alternatives other than using `[[ $var = *var2* ]]` syntax?

Comment: @Annjawn: For me, portability is extremely important and I usually run my scripts under shells that do not support the `[[` syntax.  Under those circumstances, you must use one of these (or some other) alternative.  If you do not mind restricting your script to run under a smaller set of shells, then it probably makes sense to use `[[`.