# filename match based on a known file name

Tags: bash

I want a user to input the filename which could be reside at any location but the name of the file is fixed in end .i.e. abc. txt

Let suppose the the user inputs the file name as /usr/test/abc.txt which comes in second positional parameter in my script

I want to make below statement as true how can I achieve this

```
if [ $2 == ..../abc.txt ]
```

Thanks,
Ruchir

Answer (score 4):

> `Let suppose the the user inputs the file name as /usr/test/abc.txt which comes in second positional parameter in my script`
>
> `I want to make below statement as true how can I achieve this`

Use this `if` condition using `shell glob`:

```
if [[ "/$2" == *"/abc.txt" ]]; then
    echo "valid match"
fi
```

Comment: This will fail if the $2 argument is simply 'abc.txt'

Comment: @ArunTaylor: Yes I am aware of that and I have just copied the condition from OP's question which had leading `/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use basename to get the last component of the filename.

```
prompt> cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "abc.txt" == `basename $2` ]; then
    echo "found .../abc.txt"
fi

prompt> foo.sh foo /a/b/c/abc.txt
found .../abc/txt
```

Comment: This fails if user inputs stuff with spaces or other funny symbols. **Use More Quotes**.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $2 == *"/abc.txt" ]]; then
   echo "It ends with abc.txt";
fi
```

Why `[[ ]]` works compared to `[ ]` is explained here...

["[ ]" vs. "[[ ]]" in Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063692/vs-in-bash-shell)

Comment: You need the '/' otherwise it will match xxxabc.txt

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why you think your code will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
if ( echo "$2" | grep 'abc.txt$' >/dev/null ) ; then ... ; else .... ; fi
```

or

```
if ( echo "$2" | grep '/abc.txt$' >/dev/null ) ; then ... ; else .... ; fi
```

(if you need that "/" too ?)