# Bash Shell: What is the differences in syntax?

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I've seen two ways in tutorials to do syntax for if statements in BASH shell:

This one wouldn't work unless I put quotes around the variable and added additional [ and ]:

```
if [[ "$step" -eq 0 ]]
```

This one worked without putting quotes around the variable and the additional [ and ] weren't needed:

```
if [ $step -ge 1 ] && [ $step -le 52 ]
```

Which is correct and best practice? What are the differences? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "wouldn't work".  You got an error?  Unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yes, got an error with the first one which was made to work with putting double quotes around $step and adding the additional [ and ] surrounding it.

Comment: What was the error?  What was the value of $step when you got it?

Comment: Both should work unless `$step` is empty or contains spaces

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts

Comment: don't know about "best practice", but since you're usign arithmetic expressions, you could use this valid bash: `if (( 1 <= step && step < 52 )); ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes"* -- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

`if [ $step -ge 1 ] && [ $step -le 52 ]`  can be replaced as

`if [ "$step" -ge 1 -a "$step" -le 52 ]`

`if [[ "$step" -eq 0 ]]` can be replaced as `if [ "$step" -eq 0 ]`

Also, suppose you have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $x -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "hello"
fi
```

You get this error when you run the script -- `example.sh: line 2: [: -eq: unary operator expected`

But using `if [ "$x" -eq 0 ]`

You get a different error when you run the script -- `example.sh: line 2: [: : integer expression expected`

Thus, it is always best to put variables inside quotes...

`if [[ .... ]]` syntax is particularly  useful when you have `regex` in the condition statement -- http://honglus.blogspot.com/2010/03/regular-expression-in-condition.html

EDIT: When we deal with strings --

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $x = "name"  ]
then
        echo "hello"
fi
```

You get this error when you run the script -- `example.sh: line 2: [: =: unary operator expected`

But, if you use `if [ "$x" = "name"  ]` it runs fine (i.e. no errors ) and `if` statement is evaluated as `false`, as value of `x` is `null` which does not match `name`.

Comment: So while it may work in some situations, such as dealing with single numbers for counters, it could cause problems when dealing with strings?

Comment: @Edward I have added this in the answer...pls let me know if you have more questions.