# Error executing shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute the following shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
if [ $# != 2 || $1 != "first" || $1 != "second" ]
then
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "done"
```

and I'm getting the following output:
    start
    ./autobuild.sh: line 3: [: missing `]'
    ./autobuild.sh: line 3: !=: command not found
    ./autobuild.sh: line 3: !=: command not found
    done

I have no idea how to resolve the errors. Even if I use `-ne` instead of `!=`, I get the same errors. Please help.

Comment: ***`==`*** doesn't exist in dash if you're running Ubuntu. Use ***`=`*** instead.

Comment: actually I'm getting the errors because of `!=`

Comment: I would suggest `!=` is not the actual syntax error : http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.baseadmn%2Fdoc%2Fbaseadmndita%2Fkorn_shell_conditional_exp.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. If you want multiple conditions in an if statement you need to have multiple `[]` blocks. Try:

```
if [ $# != 2 ] || [ $1 != "first" ] || [ $1 != "second" ]
```

But, it's better to use `[[` (if your shell supports it) as it is safer to use. I would go for:

```
if [[ $# -ne 2 || $1 != "first" || $1 != "second" ]]
```

See this question on brackets: [Is [[ ]] preferable over [ ] in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

While OR ing the conditions should be seperate as follows :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
if [ $# != 2]  || [ $1 != "first" ] || [ $1 != "second" ]
then
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `-NE` for `!=`.

[if-usage samples](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
if [ $# -ne 2 -o $1 -ne "first" -o $1 -ne "second" ]
then
    echo "Error"
fi
echo "done"
```