# If arguments won't read

Tags: bash, if-statement, arguments

I'm writing a VERY simple bash script with an "IF" statment.  I've written many before, but for some reason it will not read the "${hitA1} == 0" argument.  ${hitA1} is read from a file, and it is actually reading it, and it does actually equal 0.  Instead it goes to the second argument of "${hitA1} != 0".  Any ideas?

Code:

```
CorHitA1=0
MissA1=0
for i in 44 50 53 58 71
do
    late=`expr $i + 1`
    hitA1=`sed -n ${i}p _TMP_Acc1.txt`
    hitlateA1=`sed -n ${late}p _TMP_Acc1.txt`
    if [[ ${hitA1} == 0 ]]; then
        echo "HEY!!!!!"
        CorHitA1=`expr ${CorHitA1} + 1`
    elif [[ ${hitA1} != 0 ]]; then
        echo "Nope..."
        echo ${hitA1}
    fi
    echo "CorHitA1 = " ${CorHitA1}
done
```

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of your script (after `#!/bin/bash`).  It'll give you a bunch of debugging output which should make it easier to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Try adding `set -x` at the top of your script to trace the execution when running it. What's the values then? Try using `if (( ${hitA1} == 0 )); then # yes; else # nope; fi` instead.

Comment: Another [answer I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts#answer-669486) says that `[[ ... ]]` is not POSIX-compliant and may not work if you got the bash script from another platform.

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you should use `((` for arithmetic tests:

```
if ((hitA1 == 0)); then ...
```

(With arithmetic evaluation, you don't need the `$` nor do you need to quote the variable.)

Or you can use the `-eq` operator with `[[`:

```
if [[ $hitA1 -eq 0 ]]; then ...
```

If you don't do one of the above, and the line in the file you're extracting has whitespace in it, then `[[ $hitA1 == 0 ]]` will return false because `==` is string equality, and a string with whitespace is not the same as a string without.

Comment: I tried using `if ((hitA1 == 0)); then...` but I got an error message saying `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "`

Comment: @user3100107: don't use windows editors to edit bash scripts. You're running into problems with stray carriage return characters, part of the windows `CRLF` line ending protocol. Use `dos2unix` or some such to get rid of them. Also: what version of bash are you using?