# command line argument in bash gives an error

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script and one of the command line arguments is a string like `A`:

```
sh bash.sh file.in A
```

The script contains:

```
format=$2

if [$format = "A"]; then 
    ...
else 
    ...
fi
```

As a result I get this error:

```
bash.sh: line 20: [A: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX shell syntax requires a space between the [ ] brackets and the expression.

Try this:

```
if [ "$format" = "A" ]; then

...

else

...

fi
```

Also, if portability isn't a concern, you can use the more robust

```
[[ "$format" == "A" ]]
```

Additional info: [Is [[ ]] preferable over [ ] in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts)

Comment: `=` is not an assignment operator in a `test`/`[` command. `==` is only accepted by `bash`, and is arguably a bug to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've edited the incorrect part out.  Not sure I like the ambiguity of having an operator mean different things in different contexts... but I'll read up some more on it.

Comment: Since the question is tagged as `bash` shouldn't the expression be `[[ "$format" == "A" ]]`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts

Comment: There, how's that for a compromise? :)  I've been trying to not presume too much when giving answers and I try to default to as close to the as-posted question as will work.  This at least proposes an alternate option.

Comment: It's not just bash that requires the space, it's the POSIX shell syntax that requires a space between any command and its arguments. Don't forget that  `[`  is a (possibly builtin) command.

Comment: Hopefully, you guys are getting rep for this.  This answer has become a team effort :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

format="$2"

if [ "$format" = "A" ];then
   echo "Equal";
else
   echo "Not equal";
fi
```

**(OR)**

```
if [[ $format = "A" ]];then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Use `=` instead of `==`. If `==` works, so would the superior `if [[ "$format" == "A" ]]; then`.

Comment: a little explanation with the answer is always welcome