# check file existence cron job

Tags: linux, email, cron, boolean

I am trying to write a cronjob to do an action if replicationTest.txt does not exist and replicationTestSeen.txt does exist in a specific directory.  Right now what I am doing is not working.  Here is the what I am doing:

0 3 * * 0 [ [ ! -e /dv1/replicationtest/replicationTest.txt ] && [ -e /dv1/replicationtest/replicationTestSeen.txt ] ] && echo 'replication passed' | mail -s 'Replication Test Passed'  myemail@email.com || echo ' replication failed' | mail -s 'Replication failed' myemail@email.com

Even when the conditions are right for the cron to email replication passed it still emails replication failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re mixing your `test`s. This pattern of `[ [ ... ] && [ ... ] ]` should not work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts) for details. If you change your tests to this it should work:

```
[[ ! -e ... ]] && [[ -e /dv1/... ]]
```

Test your conditions outside of cron before putting them into your crontab. And make sure of [which shell your cron is actually set to use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash).