# How can I make bash evaluate IF[[ ]] from string?

Tags: bash, lambda

I am trying to create a "Lambda" style WHERE script.

I want lambdaWHERE to take piped input and pass it through if condition after given as arguments is met. Like xargs I use {} to represent what comes down the pipe.

I call command like:

ls -d EqAAL* | lambdaWHERE.sh -f {}/INFO_ACTIVETICK

I want the folder names passed through if they contain a file called INFO_ACTIVETICK

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x

ARGS=$*

while read i
do
        CMD=`echo $ARGS | sed 's/{}/'$i'/g'`

        if [[ $CMD  ]]
        then
                echo $i
        fi
done
```

But when I run it a mysterious "-n" appears...

```
$ ls -d EqAAL* | /q/lambdaWHERE.sh -f {}/INFO_ACTIVETICK
+ ARGS='-f {}/INFO_ACTIVETICK'
+ read i
++ echo -f '{}/INFO_ACTIVETICK'
++ sed 's/{}/EqAAL-1m/g'
+ CMD='-f EqAAL-1m/INFO_ACTIVETICK'
+ [[ -n -f EqAAL-1m/INFO_ACTIVETICK ]]
+ echo EqAAL-1m
EqAAL-1m
+ read i
```

How can I get the bit in the [[ ]] correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close. you only need to switch to the standard POSIX `[ $CMD ]` and it will work.

The main difference between using `[[ $CMD ]]` and `[ $CMD ]` is that the first has fewer surprises and you need not quote variables. That also means that a variable is though of as one token and cannot have a whole expression in it like you are trying.  `[ $CMD ]` however works the same way as the original shell where `[` was just a command an thus need explicit quotations in order to interpret something with spaces as one argument.

There is a [relevant question about the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/1565698) between `[[ ...]]` and `[ ..]`

Comment: But realize that doing this will make it **impossible** to use conditionals that require embedded spaces, globs, etc. as they will be expanded by the shell.

Comment: Great. That works exactly as I would like - thank you

Comment: @EtanReisner You can get around that with quoting and escaping.

Comment: @Sylwester No, you can't. Try it. Run `touch 'blah*blah' blahXblah` and then try to write a command that matches the `blah*blah` file correctly.