# How to exit loop when expression returns 0?

Tags: bash

I have this:

```
while [ "ps aux | grep '[0]:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16'" ]
do 
    echo "sleep"
    ps aux | grep "[0]:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16"
    sleep 1
done
```

This gives me:

```
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
sleep
root         7  0.5  1.5 207336 31620 ?        Sl   09:31   0:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16
sleep
root         7  0.4  1.5 207336 31620 ?        Sl   09:31   0:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16
sleep
root         7  0.3  1.5 207336 31620 ?        Sl   09:31   0:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16
...
...
...
```

How can I change my oneliner so that the loop is exited once the `ps aux | grep` returns 0 (meaning the Xvfb process is running)?

Comment: Please improve the readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, you're evaluating whether a string is non-empty (in bash, `[ "string" ]` is equivalent to `[ -n "string" ]`).

If you want to exit when the pattern is matched, use this:

```
while ! ps aux | grep -q '[0]:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16'; do 
    echo "sleep"
    sleep 1
done
```

The `-q` option to grep enables "quiet mode", so output is supressed.

Note that you could (should?) use `pgrep` instead of your pipe:

```
while ! pgrep '0:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16'; do
# ...
```

Comment: In some situations `[[` behaves less surprising, which is why I prefer `[[` over `[`. (See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts)

Comment: @Micha agreed that `[[` has its uses in bash scripts but `[[ "string" ]]`  behaves just the same as `[ "string" ]` and here, we don't even want to use `test` (or the bash extended version) at all!