# Linux bash if - elif don't work as expected

Tags: linux, bash

My Bash-Script has to do something different, according of the beginning of a Variable. 
When I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="__B something"

if [ -n $(echo "$line" | grep "^__A") ]; then
   echo "Line __A"
elif [ -n $(echo "$line" | grep "^__B") ]; then
   echo "Line __B"
elif [ -n $(echo "$line" | grep "^__C") ]; then
   echo "Line __C"
elif [ -n $(echo "$line" | grep "^__D") ]; then
   echo "Line __D"
elif [ -n $(echo "$line" | grep "^__E") ]; then
   echo "Line __E"
elif [ $(echo "$line" | grep "^__F") ]; then
   echo -n "Line __F"
else
   echo "something other"
fi
```

Bash does not recognize that the String start's with __B.:

Output is:

```
Line __A
```

What's wrong with my Script?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: it looks like you misplaced the last `-n`

Comment: Use more quotes! `if [ -n "$(echo ...)" ]; then`. Quote the parameter expansion! (but your design is pretty bad anyway).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: if you try to double quote the *whole* `echo|grep` command (not just the snip you show) you will see it is not quite so simple, particularly considering the embedded space in `$line`.

Comment: @cdarke: what about the embedded space in `$line`?

Comment: @OP: this would be a typical use for `case`! `case $line in (__A*) echo "Line __A";; (__B*) echo "Line __B";; ... (*) echo "something other";; esac`.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your script using the `xtrace` option than you can see what is happening:

```
bash -x your-script
+ line='__B something'
++ echo '__B something'
++ grep '^__A'
+ '[' -n ']'
+ echo 'Line __A'
Line __A
```

Because you use the old `test` *built-in* (otherwise known as `[`) the expansion is done but results in nothing to test except the `-n`.  Using the `[[` *keyword* will quote things correctly:

```
bash -x your-script
+ line='__B something'
++ echo '__B something'
++ grep '^__A'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
++ echo '__B something'
++ grep '^__B'
+ [[ -n __B something ]]
+ echo 'Line __B'
Line __B
```

However, using the external program `grep` is a waste.  Recent versions of `bash` have regular expressions (REs) built-in (using the binding operator `=~`) but you don't need REs in this case, simple globbing will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="__B something"

if [[ $line == __A* ]]; then
   echo "Line __A"
elif [[ $line == __B* ]]; then
   echo "Line __B"
elif [[ $line == __C* ]]; then
   echo "Line __C"
elif [[ $line == __D* ]]; then
   echo "Line __D"
elif [[ $line == __E* ]]; then
   echo "Line __E"
elif [[ $line == __F* ]]; then
   echo -n "Line __F"
else
   echo "something other"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the subtleties of the difference between using `[[` and `[` in bash if conditionals.

You can either use `[[` and `]]` everywhere (seems to work), e.g.

```
if [[ -n $(echo "$line" | grep "^__A") ]]; then
   echo "Line __A"
```

or you can quote the subshell like this

```
if [ -n "$(echo '$line' | grep '^__A')" ]; then
   echo "Line __A"
```

> `[[` has fewer surprises and is generally safer to use. But it is not
>   portable - Posix doesn't specify what it does and only some shells
>   support it (beside bash, i heard ksh supports it too). For example,
>   you can do
>
> `[[ -e $b ]]`
>
> to test whether a file exists. But with `[`, you have to quote `$b`,
>   because it splits the argument and expands things like `"a*"` (where `[[`
>   takes it literally). That has also to do with how `[` can be an external
>   program and receives its argument just normally like every other
>   program (although it can also be a builtin, but then it still has not
>   this special handling).

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/669486/5272567) answer here on stackoverflow. So in your case, most likely bash is separating your string on a space and that is having some side effects.