# Storing an error message in bash only if it fails

Tags: bash

I am a beginner with bash so I apologize if this is a basic question or has syntax issues but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.  I want to run a command, and if it fails, check if the error message matches a certain string.  Here is what I have:

```
err_msg=`./command input.txt 2>&1`
if [$? -eq 1]
then 
   if [err_msg -eq "Error: timeout"]
   then
       #do something
   fi
fi
```

Is this the correct way to do this?  If I'm using the first line to define the error message err_msg, will $? still store the pass/fail status of the command? Also, what will happen to if the command passes?  Will err_msg just be blank?

Comment: You have some syntax errors: 1. leave a space around the characters `[` and `]`: these are builtins and need to have a space around them to be recognized as such. 2. Don't use `-eq` to test for equality of strings. Use `=` instead. Re. your question: yes, `$?` will expand to the return code of the command.

Comment: Thank you! Also, should err_msg be $err_msg in the 2nd if statement since it's a variable?

Comment: Yes, of course, you want to check for _the expansion_ of `err_msg`. You also need to _quote_ this expansion: `"$err_msg"`, unless you use the more robust keyword `[[`.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use the old-style backquote form of command substitution, use `$(command)` instead
- Use `[[ ]]` for testing instead of `[ ]` as it has [more features and fewer surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash)
- `-eq` is used for integer comparison. For string comparison, use `=` or `==`
- Note that command can fail with an exit status **other** than 1, thus it's better to test for non-zero status: `! [[ $? -eq 0 ]]`
- You **can** use `$?` for testing exit status of the last command or you can test it with `if` directly: `if command; then echo CMD OK; fi`
- You can assign output of a command to a variable while testing its exit code

Using the points above, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
if ! err_msg=$(./command input.txt 2>&1)
then 
   if [[ $err_msg = "Error: timeout" ]]; then
      echo "Doing something.."
   fi
fi
```

Comment: You can also use `! err_msg=$(...) && [[ $err_msg = "..." ]]` to avoid the nested `if` statement.

Comment: @chepner Exactly. However, I found that a bit too confusing for a beginner.