# How to delete specific sym links in $HOME given a list of their coordinating files in O(n lg n)?

Tags: bash

I've made a manager for my dot files that creates sym links between each of the dot files in my dot_files/ dir and my $HOME.

I'm trying to write a script that deletes all of these specific sym links and no others.

Here's my O(n^2) solution that does the job fine.

```
delete_sym_links () {
    # Include dot (.) files while looping
    shopt -s dotglob

    for DOT_FILE in ~/dot_files/*;
    do
        if [ ! -d "$DOT_FILE" ];
        then
            for FILE in ~/*;
            do
                if [ -h "$FILE" ] && [ $(basename $DOT_FILE) = $(basename $FILE) ];
                then
                    rm "$FILE"
                    echo deleted "$FILE"
                fi
            done
        fi
    done
}
```

I'm trying to get the runtime down to O(n lg n). The bash is really tripping me up though.

Something like...

```
delete_sym_links () {
    SYM_LINKS=($(find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls | sort -n))
    NUM_SYM_LINKS=$(find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls | wc -l)
    DOT_FILES=$(find $HOME/dot_files/ -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -type f | sort -n)
    NUM_DOT_FILES=$(find $HOME/dot_files/ -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -type f | wc -l)

    i=0
    j=0

    while (("$i" < "$NUM_SYM_LINKS")) && (("$j" < "$NUM_DOT_FILES"));
    do
        if [ $(basename ${SYM_LINKS[$i]}) = $(basename ${DOT_FILES[$j]}) ];
        then
            echo removing sym link ${SYM_LINKS[$i]}
            rm ${SYM_LINKS[$i]}
            ((j++))
        else
            ((i++))
        fi
    done

    echo "All dot_files sym links removed"
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping over every file in your home directory when you know what the name should be? Essentially you could do what you were already doing in your n^2 version, but just set $FILE to `~/$(basename $DOT_FILE)`.

Comment: Even ignoring the big-O complexity, your constant factors are going to kill you on some of this (for any significantly-sized `n`) as the code is currently written -- `$(...)` is itself a slow operation, and running external commands (like basename) pays a large penalty as well.

Comment: Re: `arr=( $(find ...) )`, see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) -- that's not just a practice with performance issues but major correctness problems (a filename with spaces will be split into multiple array elements; a filename that can be expanded as a glob *will* be, and the results subject to `globfail` or `nullglob` behaviors if enabled; etc); better practices are discussed in [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: ...in particular, consider `readarray -t -d '' arr < <(find ... -print0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean, O(n), code:

```
function delete_symlinks
{
    local df_path df_name home_df_path

    for df_path in ~/dot_files/.* ; do
        [[ -d $df_path ]] && continue
        df_name=${df_path##*/}
        home_df_path=~/$df_name
        if [[ -L $home_df_path ]] ; then
            rm -- "$home_df_path"
            printf 'deleted %s\n' "$home_df_path"
        fi
    done

    return 0
}
```

- It uses a ksh-style function definition (a personal preference).
- All variables are localized to avoid clashes with global variables.
- Lowercase is used for all variable names.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).
- It uses `[[` instead of `[` for tests.  See [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/4154375)
- `${var##*/}` is used instead of `$(basename $var)` for safety and speed.  See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).
- `printf` is used instead of `echo` for safety.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).
- As in the code in the question, no attempt is made to check that the symlink being deleted actually links to the corresponding file under 'dotfiles'.  I would fix this in a real program because it might remove a manually-created symlink.

Comment: Great, well-referenced answer; I find myself upvoting it despite the ksh function declaration syntax :P

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has associative arrays. We can store a unique identifier for each dotfile and then check the home directory files for a match.
I believe this is O(m+n) compared to your original O(m*n).

Here's an example using inode:

```
delete_sym_links () (
    declare -A inode
    shopt -s dotglob nullglob

    ls -diL ~/dot_files/* | (
        while read i name; do
            [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue
            inode2name[$i]="$name"
        done
        for name in ~/*; do
            [ ! -h "$name" ] && continue

            read i junk <<<$( ls -diL "$name" )
            if [ "$junk" != "$name" ]; then
                echo 1>&2 "ls parse error! ($name)"
            fi
            if [ -n "${inode2name[i]}" ]; then
                echo "found: $name -> ${inode2name[$i]}"
                echo "rm \"$name\""
            fi
        done
    )
)
```

- As `~/dot_files/` is a subdirectory of `~/`, I have assumed they are on the same filesystem so that inode can be used as the unique id.
- Parsing `ls` (in the `while` loop) is frowned upon but is a portable way to extract the inode as long as we don't have strange filenames (eg. with embedded newlines). We only need [POSIX options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html).
- We call `ls` rather a lot in the `for` loop so it could have a big effect on the constant factor of the complexity, but it's only on possible matches so perhaps it's not so bad.
- Using `fn()()` instead of more common `fn(){}` localises the `shopt`

If we don't like parsing `ls` but we have `realpath`, we can do:

```
delete_sym_links () (
    declare -A real
    shopt -s dotglob nullglob

    for name in ~/dot_files/*; do
        [ ! -f "name" ] && continue
        real="$(realpath "$name")"
        real2name["$real"]="$name"
    done

    for name in ~/*; do
        [ ! -h "$name" ] && continue
        real="$(realpath "$name")"
        if [ -n "${real2name["$real"]}" ]; then
            echo 1>&2 "found: $name -> ${real2name["$real"]}"
            echo "rm \"$name\""
        fi
    done
)
```