# Confusion about bash file exists test operator

Tags: bash

The following returns nothing:

```
which asdf
```

So why does the if statement get triggered here?

```
x=$(which asdf)
if [ -f $x ]; then echo "exists"; fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't quote `$x`, so your test becomes `[ -f ]`, which is true because `-f` is a non-empty string.

```
if [ -f "$x" ]; then
```

Comment: @Amadan: Bash will complain about `[[ -f ]]` but it won't complain about a null or unset variable (quoted or not) or a null string, it will evaluate to `false`. `nullvar=""; [[ -f $nullvar ]]`, `unset unsetvar; [[ -f $unsetvar ]]`, `[[ -f "" ]]` and `[[ -f \  ]]` (that's two spaces after the backslash) all evaluate to `false` without an error.

Answer (score 1):

Though Chepner has given good solution, in case you want to look for an alternate approach then try following once.

```
which asdf 2>&1 >/dev/null && echo "exists"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to check if a command exists.  It is better to use the `command` builtin instead of `which` in that context, like this:

```
if command -v asdf; then
    echo "exists"
fi
```

To learn more about `command`, try `help command`.

## Related:

- [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/6862601)
- [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/6862601)