# Bash Script how to show filename case by case

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameters

I make file "my.sh" and in the file I write code

```
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   echo "filename: $0"
fi
```

and I execute `my.sh` file

`$ my.sh` -> I want output [`filename: my.sh`]

however, the result shows [`filename: ./my.sh`]

I finally want when I enter `my.sh`, the output shows [`filename: my.sh`] and when I enter `./my.sh`, the output shows [`filename: ./my.sh`]

Comment: `echo "filename: ${0##*/}"`? (using bash *parameter expansion with substring removal*) Also, you cannot execute `my.sh` alone without `./my.sh` unless `my.sh` is in a directory in your `PATH`.

Comment: And what happens when you run `/home/me/my.sh`? Do you strip `/home/me/`? Or do you only strip relative directories, like `../` and `./`? And how about paths like `/home/me/../me/../me/my.sh`?

Comment: `[ $# = 0 ]` is incorrect and should 'technically' be `[ $# -eq 0 ]` so that an integer, rather than a string, comparison is made.

Comment: when i run "$ /home/fold/proj/my.sh", the result is filename: /home/fold/proj/my.sh

Comment: Additionally, I only run the file in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   echo $(basename $0)
fi
```

Also, take a note that `[[` is generally [safer to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba).