# Trying logical comparisons in bash

Tags: bash, logical-operators

I am just trying to get something straight as to why the following returns false:

```
echo $[ $(( 2100%4 )) == 0 ] --> returns '1'
```

I know I am probably missing something simple.

Comment: @Carcigenicate : Shell scripting has a different meaning for truth and false, so `0` indicates "no problem" (i.e.success, true), while any non-zero number is available to report a particular documented error, i.e. file not found, can't access file, etc although may programs just return `1` (false) for any/all errors. Read the man page for the particular cmd you are checking. You can see this for yourself by typing `true` and the immediately `echo $?` is the return status of the most recently executed cmd and `false ; echo $?` will return `1`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter : I thought the same, do you think you could possibly explain as to why the expression I am testing is returning false then?

Comment: It's my recollection that the form `$[ LHSexpr test RHSexpr]` (using the leading `$`) is an ancient form.So I can't speak for that. POSIX tests are done like `if [ LHSexpr test RHSexpr]`, and `bash/ksh/zsh` offer an advanced test with `if [[ .... ]] ; ..` which allows even more advanced testing. Sorry can't get an URL for you now. Hm .. just noticed you're using `$((  math ))` which indicates you're using a feature rich shell. If you are using the leading `echo` to debug, I would remove that and uset `set -vx` to see the levels of evaluation inside your code. Good luck.

Comment: As you are using a shell with `$((...))`. then I'd recommend rewriting your test like `if  (( 2100%4 == 0 ))  ; then echo returned $? ; else echo else returned $? ;`. Note that `if  (( 2100%8 == 0 ))  ; then echo returned $? ; else echo else returned $? ; fi` returns the `else` error message (as it should). Good luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba/669486?r=SearchResults&s=3|55.4521#669486 will probably have all the detail you need. Good luck.

Comment: `$[...]` is an old form of `$((...))` and the arithmetic expression `0 == 0` is evaluated to be `1` as other languages.

Answer (score 2):

In short "meaning" differs from "value".

A zero exit status means success. A nonzero exit status means failure.

A zero value is associated with "false" boolean state. A nonzero value is associated with "true" boolean state.

The `[ ... ]` is the same as `test ...`. The `test` command exits with a nonzero exit status if the expression inside is false (as in really false, not true). The `test` command exits with a zero exit status if the expression inside is true.

The `$[ ... ]` is an old, [undocumented and deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) form of `$(( ... ))` arithmetic expansion (there's also the `expr ...` that you should not use).

The `if expr; then body; fi` executes the `body` part only if `expr` exits with a zero exit status, ie. meaning "success" here.

So:

```
echo $[ $(( 2100%4 )) == 0 ]
```

will print `1`. The `$(( 2100%4 ))` will do the arithmetic operation and expand to `0`. The arithmetic expansion work as in C language. The result of `==` arithmetic operation is `1` if the numbers are equal, it's `0` if the numbers are not equal. The `$[ 0 == 0 ]` will do the arithmetic operation and expand to just a number `1`, as this will be the result of `==` operator.

While the:

```
[ $(( 2100%4 )) == 0 ]
```

Executes the `[ 0 == 0 ]`, it's same as `test 0 == 0`. Because the expression `0 == 0` evaluated by `test` command is true, so `test` command exits with `0` exit status, which means "success". Note that `==` is a bash extension for `=` and it does *string* comparison, it compares `0` to `0` lexicographically. It does not compare numbers and it differs from arithmetic operator.

There is also bash extension `(( ... ))` syntax. The `(( ... ))` evaluates the arithmetic *expression* and if the result of arithmetic is equal to "true" boolean state (ie. it result in a nonzero value), then the `(( .. ))` exits with a zero exit status (meaning success). If the expression evaluates to 0, ie. "false" boolean state, then the `(( ... ))` exits with a nonzero exit status. Note the difference.

So you can:

```
if (( 2100%4 == 0 )); then something; fi
```

The `2100%4 == 0` is equal to `1`, which is "true" boolean state, which means `((` exits with a zero exit status, which means success, which means the body of the `if` will execute.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my comments. I don't think I ever understood before why "`2100%4 == 0` is equal to `1`", but your explanation makes it clear. Thanks!