# Error when checking for substring in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, 64-bit, x86-64

I'm quite new to shell scripting and have encountered an issue when trying to check for substrings within a string.
I want to build code that checks if you are running a 64bit-based system. This is indicated by the output of the `uname -m && cat /etc/*release` command by the `x86_64` in the first line.

Here's my code:

```
INFO=$(uname -m && cat /etc/*release)
if [ "$INFO" == *"x86_64"* ]
then
    echo "You are running a 64bit-based system!"
else
    echo "Your system architecture is wrong!"
    exit
fi
```

Although I run a 64-bit based system and the x86_64 shows up in the output of my command, the if statement still returns false, so I get the output `Your system architecture is wrong!`. It should be the opposite.
Can someone help me out by identifying what I did wrong? I also accept general suggestions for improving my approach, but in the first place, I'd like to know where the bug is.

*Many thanks for your help!*

Comment: Note that Arch Linux's `/etc/arch_release` doesn't contain the string `x86` or `x86_64`.  (It has some lines like `PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux"` and `BUILD_ID=rolling`).  Perhaps `file /bin/ls` would be more portable as a way to check the user-space bitness.  (As opposed to kernel bitness with `uname -a`, which might be a 64-bit kernel running 32-bit user-space.)

Comment: Are you running this script with `/bin/sh` or with `/bin/bash` or something else?

Comment: @glennjackman I'm running with /bin/bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> [
> ```

The command `[` is equivalent to [test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command. `test` doesn't support any kind of advanced matching. `test` can compare strings with `=` - comparing strings with `==` in `test` is a bash extension.

By doing:

```
[ "$INFO" == *"x86_64"* ]
```

You are actually running command like `[ "$INFO" == <the list of files that match`*"x86_64"*`pattern> ]` - the `*"x86_64"*` undergoes filename expansion. If you would have a file named `something_x86_64_something` it would be placed there, the same way `cat *"x86_64"*` would work.

The bash extensions [`[[` command](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) supports pattern matching. Do:

```
if [[ "$INFO" == *"x86_64"* ]]
```

For portable scripting that will always work with any kind of posix shell use `case`:

```
case "$INFO" in
*x86_64*) echo yes; ;;
*) echo no; ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash version >= 3 you can use a regex:

```
[[ "$INFO" =~ x86_64 ]]
```

Comment: Possible, but unnecessary, because globbing `[[ $INFO == *x86_64* ]] would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure why it's so but your code starts working after doubling the square brackets:

```sh
INFO=$(uname -m && cat /etc/*release)
if [[ "$INFO" = *x86_64* ]]
then
    echo "You are running a 64bit-based system!"
else
    echo "Your system architecture is wrong!"
    exit
fi
```

Perhaps some explanation can be found under [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba) and alikes.

Comment: Sure. Double-brackets ensure that globbing is done on the left-hand side of the operation, i.e. `$INFO`, and not to the files in the directory. BTW, you can omit the double-quotes, if you want to, since no word splitting is done in this situtation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check 64 bit is to simply grep the output of /bin/arch

```
if  /bin/arch | grep -q x86_64
then
  echo "it is 64 bit"
else
  echo "it is not"
fi
```