# Understanding bash's 'test -z' vs 'test -n'

Tags: bash

I think I understand `-z`.  If a variable is empty `test` will return true.
But I don't understand `-n`.  `man test` tells me:

```
     -n string     True if the length of string is nonzero.
```

So I execute these command lines:

```
bash-3.2$ thing=abc
bash-3.2$ test -z $thing && echo "x${thing}x"
bash-3.2$ test -n $thing && echo "x${thing}x"
xabcx
bash-3.2$ thing=""
bash-3.2$ test -z $thing && echo "x${thing}x"
xx
bash-3.2$ test -n $thing && echo "x${thing}x"
xx
```

Why does `test -n $thing && echo "x${thing}x"` output `xx`?
Doesn't `$thing` have a length of zero?
Shouldn't `test -n $thing` have returned false?

Comment: It seems that both `test -z` and `test -n` (without further arguments) return success, but I can't find anything in the manual about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$thing` is null, so as soon as it gets dereferenced, it stops existing on the command line, and so it never gets delivered as an argument to `test`.

To fix this, quote it:

```
$ test -n "$thing" && echo "x${thing}x"
$
```

See [When should I wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/4518341)

---

Or, a better solution is to avoid `test` and `[ ]` altogether, and use `[[ ]]` instead.

```
$ [[ -n $thing ]] && echo "x${thing}x"
$
```

See [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/4518341)