# Bash shell if operator

Tags: zsh

I write a function like this to `.commands` file, and I imported `.commands` in `.zshrc`

```
function testA() {
  echo "start"
  if [ "$1" == "a" ]; then
    echo "ok"
  fi
  echo "end"
}
```

And when I run `testA a` in terminal

```
start
testA:2: = not found
```

What is the problem here?
[image: Result]

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code? I am getting `start ok end` just fine. How are you sourcing the function code into your Bash session?

Comment: Use `if [[ "a" == "a" ]]; then`

Comment: Are you sure you are using bash? what does `echo $0` say?

Comment: This doesn't look like Bash. Bash does not have a builtin `which` that can display shell functions. Only Zsh has a builtin `which` command that matches your output. (Also I've never seen anyone decorating Bash like that).

Comment: `echo $0` says `-zsh`

Comment: So why are you putting Bash in your question title, and tagging [tag:bash]? In case you weren't aware, Bash and Zsh are two vastly different (though partially compatible) shell implementations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/are-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-b

Comment: @iBug sorry for my lack of knowledge. I though they were the same.

Comment: A single "=" in the test is enough, why use two? Try "help test" in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 12 – "Conditional Expressions" of the [`zsh` documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions) states:

> A *conditional expression* is used with the `[[` compound command to test attributes of files and to compare strings.

This means, changing your conditional expression to use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` should make it work:

```
function testA() {
  echo "start"
  if [[ "$1" == "a" ]]; then
    echo "ok"
  fi
  echo "end"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the problem to simply type a `[a == a]` or `echo ==`. This will also produce this error. The reason is that a `=` has specific meaning to zsh, unless it is followed by a white space.

You have three possible workarounds:

Either quote that parameter, i.e.

```
[ $1 "==" a ]
```

or use a single equal sign, i.e.

```
[ $1 = a ]
```

or use `[[`, which introduces a slightly different parsing context:

```
[[ $1 == a ]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $ cat fun.sh
  function test() {
  echo "start"
  if [ "a" == "a" ]; then
    echo "ok"
  fi
  echo "end"
}
```

**Source script file**

```
 $ source fun.sh
```

**Output:**

```
$ test
start
ok
end
```