# bash script to compare one line to a variable

Tags: bash, debian

This seems like a basic thing yet I can't get it work properly.  I have a bash script where I want to compare the OS version (11 or 12 in Debian's case) and do something depending on the version.  Here is what I have:

```
if [ cat /etc/*release | sed -n '3p' | cut -c 13-14 == '12' ]
then
   perform actions
```

The command above works on the command line on Debian 11 (without the comparison) and prints out either 11 or 12.  However, running it on Debian 12 says it is Debian 11.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This cannot possibly work on Debian 11 either.

Comment: See [Bash Script To Find Debian Release Number from /etc/debian_version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109958/264812).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# first approach getting version from /etc/os-release
version=$(awk -F'"' '/^VERSION_ID=/{print $2}' /etc/os-release)
echo "$version"
if [ "$version" -eq 12 ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi

# second approach getting version from /etc/debian_version
version=$(</etc/debian_version)
echo "$version"
if [[ "$version" =~ ^12\. ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

---

output:

```
12
true
12.0
true
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

For starters, a [UUoC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award). Why `cat file|sed`? Just `sed -n '3p' /etc/*release`. I'd also skip the extraneous `cut`. On my Centos: `sed -n '/^VERSION=/{s/[^0-9]//g;p}' /etc/*release` gives me `7`. Likewise, if you are using `bash` you should almost always use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]`, for several reasons, though there are arguments on [either side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/are-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-b) - just know the syntax for whichever you are using.

The real problem here, though, is that you need a `$(...)` subshell, or at least backticks.

```
$: if [ cat /etc/*release | sed -n '3p' | cut -c 13-14 == '12' ] ; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
-bash: [: missing `]'
cut: ==: No such file or directory
cut: 12: No such file or directory
cut: ]: No such file or directory
no

$: if [[ `cat /etc/*release | sed -n '3p' | cut -c 13-14` == '12' ]] ; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
no

$: if grep -q '^VERSION_ID="7"' /etc/*release; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
ok

$: if [[ 7 == $(sed -n $'/^VERSION_ID=/!d\ns/[^0-9]//g' /etc/*release) ]] ; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
ok

$: if [[ 7 == $(awk '/^VERSION_ID=/{print gensub(/[^0-9]/,"","g")}' /etc/*release) ]] ; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
ok
```

I recommend the first one, the `grep` with no brackets at all, which is doing *exactly* what you want without embedding it into some other syntax. (Obviously you'd want to change the 7 to a 12, or some appropriate pattern, but I recommend keeping the quotes.)

When something isn't working, paste your code at [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It will often help.

```
 
Line 1:
if [ cat /etc/*release | sed -n '3p' | cut -c 13-14 == '12' ]
^-- SC1009 (info): The mentioned syntax error was in this if expression.
   ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this test expression. Fix to allow more checks.
     ^-- SC1014 (warning): Use 'if cmd; then ..' to check exit code, or 'if [[ $(cmd) == .. ]]' to check output.
         ^-- SC1072 (error): Expected test to end here (don't wrap commands in []/[[]]). Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
         ^-- SC1076 (error): Trying to do math? Use e.g. [ $((i/2+7)) -ge 18 ].
```

You should also confirm that the record you want looks like the pattern I'm checking in Debian. You're apparently looking at `VERSION_ID` (I was checking `VERSION`) so I updated that.

Comment: I will try that. Your answer (just using sed, without the cat) didn't work on a Deb 11 box,- I get an error "sed -e expression#1, char 21, unknown command '/' " but I'll play around to see what I can do.

Comment: Maybe a GNU specific issue. Edited for a more generic use, and added an `awk` version, as well as a `grep` that is better anyway.

Comment: or `if grep '^12\.' /etc/debian_version` or `if [[ $(</etc/debian_version) = 12.* ]]` (or maybe `12*`).