Getting a "-bash: [: : integer expression expected" error on bash shell startup in arch
Anytime I startup my bash shell I'm getting this pervasive "-bash: [: : integer expression expected" error, which leads me to my .xinitrc, .bashrc, and .bash_profile. I just chaged my /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc before this started happening, which leads me to believe it's related, but I'm stumped.
I was in the process of setting up xrdp, which might be a factor.
~/.xinitrc
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then







    xrdb -merge $sysresources

fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then







    xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

exec i3
#exec sh /home/username/.screenlayout/display.sh

~/.bashrc
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
alias i3-config='vim .config/i3/config'
alias polybar-config='vim .config/polybar/config'
alias wallpaper='feh --bg-fill --randomize /home/username/Pictures/Wallpapers/'
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE='google-chrome-stable'
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk'
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/android-sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/flutter/bin
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin
source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh
export GITLAB_API_TOKEN='blahblahblah'
export NPM_TOKEN='blahblahblah'
alias tailscale-torrent='sudo tailscale up --exit-node=xxx --exit-node-allow-lan-access=false'
alias tailscale-normal='sudo tailscale up --exit-node= --reset'
alias dvorak='setxkbmap us dvorak'
alias us='setxkbmap us'
alias pia-client='/opt/piavpn/bin/pia-client'
alias vmware-background='sudo vmware &'

umask 002
export SYSTEMD_EDITOR=vim

~/.bash_profile
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

if [ -z "${DISPLAY}" ] && [ "${XDG_VTNR}" -eq 1 ]; then
        exec startx
fi

/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then







    xrdb -merge $sysresources

fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then







    xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi


twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login

I've tried cleaning up my bashrc and bash_profile with no luck

[ "${XDG_VTNR}" -eq 1 ] what if XDG_VTNR is not a number.

Please use https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance. You have a lot of unquoted variables; see also When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

More specifically, the empty string that "${XDG_VTNR}" produces when the variable is not set is not a number.

Don't use -eq at all; you don't care if XDG_VTNR is a number, only that it is the string 1, so use =.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag info.

You could easily find out by yourself, which line in your files is actually producing the error. It's not necessary that you dump all your startup files into your question and let people do the analysis.

Replace [ "${XDG_VTNR}" -eq 1 ] in your .bash_profile with [ "${XDG_VTNR}" = 1 ] so your .bash_profile looks like this:
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

if [ -z "${DISPLAY}" ] && [ "${XDG_VTNR}" = 1 ]; then
        exec startx
fi

That should remove the error in the case that $XDG_VTNR is not set or not a number.
For consistency in the usage of [ or [[ you may also want to change the line above, so your .bash_profile would look like this:
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc

if [ -z "${DISPLAY}" ] && [ "${XDG_VTNR}" = 1 ]; then
        exec startx
fi

But that's a matter of taste.

POSIX is =, not ==, but I guess that doesn't matter since we are using bash

It seems odd to use [ and [[ in the same line.  Frankly, it seems weird to use both [ and [[ in the same script, but that may just be my personal opinion influenced by the belief  that using [[ is always a bad idea.  It would be better to be consistent and pick either [[ or [ to use everywhere.

Interesting take. I hold the opposite view: when writing bash-specific code it's a bad idea not to use [[

Thanks for your comments, I adjusted the answer to be more consistent and POSIX conform. @glennjackman why is [[ always better than [ when using bash?

@kzi [[ is special in bash and doesn't need escaping in many cases

@kzi see https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/1745001 for why to use [[.

[[ allows for regex matching with =~ operator, glob matching with ==, string comparison with < and >, and other features.
