Split PDF depending on "Job Separation" pages (barcode)
I have large PDF Files with "Job Separation", sometime called "Patch Code"-Pages in between. I want to split the PDF into multiple PDF-Files, where the "Job Separation"-Page" marks the end of each file.
1
I know that most of the professional scanning software has the ability to divide the output into different files depending on special "Patch Code" sheets, but here I do not want use client-software for scanning. I receive the scans via file-share or Email and look for an easy solution (possibly bash script) to split the PDF-File.
I looked into ghostscript,pdftk, cpdf, tesseract. None of them seems to support "Patch Code" Separation.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the tips, I gave up searching for a PDF tool which recognize Patch-Code Pages. So I ended up doing OCR on the scans, and split, merge the PDF according to the position of the Patch-Code
# we Split single PDF in PDF-per-page with pdftk
# later we concatenate Multiple-Single-Page PDF according to Patch-Code pages
# standard creates files as pg_%04d.pdf -> pg_0001.pdf
# here we creat 0001.pdf ...

pdftk $fname burst output %04d.pdf


# Create array with either Filename "00XX.pdf" or "Patch-Code"

declare -a PDFArray
for i in 0*
do
    # OCR over all PDFs in TMP Folder. "--sidecar" creates .txt files with OCR recognized text
    ocrmypdf -l deu "$i" "$i" --sidecar
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/are-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-b
    # Test for Patch-Code, 29char and has text "Patch Code"
    if [[ "$(wc -c < "${i}.txt")" == 29 && "$(grep -c 'Patch Code' < "${i}.txt")" == 1 ]] ; then
            PDFArray+=(Patch-Code)
    else
            PDFArray+=("${i}")

    fi



# Add Patch-Code to the end of the Array
PDFArray+=( Patch-Code )


# probably doubled
PDFFiles=$(echo "${PDFArray[*]}" | perl -pe 's/\n/''/g')  
echo "$PDFFiles" | perl -pe 's/Patch-Code/\n/g' | awk '!/^$/' | while read line 
do
    #some debug
    echo "line = $line"     
    echo $line | xargs
    # Test for Number of fields. If only one with dont need to merge
    # Naming is merge-1st-Filename.pdf
    NumFields=$(echo $line | awk -F' ' "{ print NF }")
    if [[ $NumFields == 1 ]] ; then
            # xargs to trim output probably not needed
            mv $(echo $line | xargs)  merge-"$line"
    else
            FirstElement=$( echo $line | awk '{print$1}' )
            echo "FirstElement = $FirstElement"
            pdftk $(echo $line | xargs)  cat output merge-"$FirstElement"
    fi

done

                                                                                                                                                               


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't think there is any specific support for such sheets in PDF. If you can supply an example file, we can perhaps suggest something.

One possibility is that the patch sheet uses a font not used on other pages - a couple I downloaded from Kodak do this. Then you could just use cpdf -list-fonts in.pdf and grep for the page numbers...
