# Bash script directory detection and creation

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that depends on a group of folders existing, but dont want to create the folders by hand every time I use the script on a new machine.

Right now I have the following for directory detection and creation (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script)):

```
for i in {7..0}
do
  if [ ! -d "backup.${i}" ]; then
    mkdir backup.${i}
  fi
done
```

This detects and creates the folders 'backup.0' through 'backup.7' just fine, but there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mkdir -p backup.{0..7}
```