# How to check if a file is a directory

Tags: bash

What would be the best means of being able to check whether a specified path (./filename followed by the filepath) is a directory? Ideally I would also be looking to print the list of the files within the directory should they be present. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [Check if passed argument is file or directory in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665051/check-if-passed-argument-is-file-or-directory-in-bash).

The following script should do the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSED=$1
if [[ -d $PASSED ]]; then
    echo "$PASSED is a directory"
elif [[ -f $PASSED ]]; then
    echo "$PASSED is a file"
else
    echo "$PASSED is not valid"
    exit 1
fi
```

Double square brackets is a bash extension to `[ ]`. It doesn't require variables to be quoted, not even if they contain spaces.

Also worth trying: `-e` to test if a path exists without testing what type of file it is.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the response. That works well. How would I also be able to list the contents of the directory within the same script?

Comment: You could put in a ls to list the contents of the directory. I do believe that I answered your question of how to check to see if a file is a directory.

Comment: Once you have checked that a directory exists, you can then further check with `-r` that it is readable to the current user. If so, then you can list the contents with the `ls` command (generally either plain `ls` or `ls -1` (that's -ONE) when used within a script)