# How to check directory exist or not in linux.?

Tags: linux, shell

Given a file path (e.g. `/src/com/mot`), how can I check whether `mot` exists, and create it if it doesn't using Linux or shell scripting??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a directory exists in a Bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-can-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With bash/sh/ksh, you can do:

```
if [ ! -d /directory/to/check ]; then
    mkdir -p /directory/toc/check
fi
```

For files, replace `-d` with `-f`, then you can do whatever operations you need on the non-existant file.

Comment: You don't actually need the check. `mkdir -p` doesn't act on an existing directory.

Comment: That's a fair point. I'll leave it in though as if gives the OP the framework in case they wants to do other things before the `mkdir`.

Comment: Note that this gives a race condition in the case that the directory is created between the first and second line.

Comment: @Sjoerd Indeed, but that race condition (although with a much smaller window of probability) will also occur if you just use `mkdir -p` (unless some filesystem implements, and exposes, an atomic check-or-create function call). At least in the code above the mkdir call will not fail if invoked spuriously for an existing directory (because of the `-p` option provided anyway).

Comment: @Christian If you want an atomic check-or-create function, look no further than mkdir(2)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry, but I don't get that. According to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) mkdir(2) will fail with `EEXIST` if the specified directory exists. Not the behavior of `mkdir(1) -p`. At least on Solaris (I don't know about Linux) the behavior of the `-p` option is implemented using a [library routine](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/libgen/common/mkdirp.c#52) which iterates using `access()` and `mkdir()` for each path component - not atomic. I might be totally off regarding your comment however ;-)

Comment: @Christian: mkdir (without -p) is often used in shell scripts as a way to acquire a lock.  I read sjoerd's comment as applying to the case without -p

Answer (score 10):

**Check for directory exists**

```
if [ -d "$DIRPATH" ]; then
    # Add code logic here 
fi
```

**Check for directory does not exist**

```
if [ ! -d "$DIRPATH" ]; then
    # Add code logic here
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

[`mkdir -p`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) creates the directory without giving an error if it already exists.

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you only check for the directory to create it if it does not exist, you might as well just use:

```
mkdir -p /src/com/mot
```

[`mkdir -p`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mkdir.html) will create the directory if it does not exist, otherwise does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

```
test -d /src/com/mot || mkdir /src/com/mot
```

Answer (score 3):

This is baisc, but I think it works. You'll have to set a few variables if you're looking to have a dynamic list to cycle through and check.

```
if [ -d /src/com/mot ];
then
    echo Directory found
else
    mkdir /src/com/mot
fi
```

Hope that's what you were looking for...

Comment: You're missing the ';' after the closing ']' of the if-clause.

Comment: @Chirstian The ';' is not needed after the ']', and the ']' is not a closing bracket.  In the case of the command '[', the trailing ']' is just an argument to that command.  The newline serves the same purpose as the semi-colon.

Comment: @WilliamPursell My comment was regarding the first revision of the question, which did not contain a newline after the ']' after the "test" command (or "brackets", sorry for missnaming it), in which case the ';' is required before the `then`, isn't it?

Comment: @christian, yes, either a newline or a ; is required.  When I saw the question, the newline was in place.