# How to check if a directory exists within a given path

Tags: bash, ubuntu, if-statement

I'm creating a simple script for backing up and I want to check if a directory exists in a given path like so:

```
fullPath=/usr/local/webapps/mydir

if mydir exists in my $fullPath

    then back it up
    else give error
fi
```

My question is how do I formulate the if statement to check if the last directory exists in the **$fullPath** variable? Just to clarify, for this case it would be **mydir** if I used /usr/local it would be **local** etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Duplicate question? [Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
fi
```

The $DIRECTORY is the pathname

For your case, you can just do:

```
if [ -d "$fullPath" ]; then
    then back it up
    else give error
fi
```

Comment: Thank you sir, and sorry if it's duplicate I looked for 30min and couldn't find an answer.