# How to check if filepath is mounted in OS X using bash?

Tags: macos, bash

How do I perform the mount only if it has not already been mounted?

This is on OS X 10.9 and this is what I have currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Local mount point
LOCALMOUNTPOINT="/folder/share"

# Perform the mount if it does not already exist
if ...
then
/sbin/mount -t smbfs //user:password@serveraddress/share $LOCALMOUNTPOINT

else
    echo "Already mounted"
fi
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While @hd1's answer gives you whether the file exists, it does not necessary mean that the directory is mounted or not. It is possible that the file happen to exist if you use this script for different machines or use different mount points. I would suggest this

```
LOCALMOUNTPOINT="/folder/share"

if mount | grep "on $LOCALMOUNTPOINT" > /dev/null; then
    echo "mounted"
else
    echo "not mounted"
fi
```

Note that I include "on" in grep statement based on what `mount` command outputs in my machine. You said you use MacOS so it should work, but depending on what `mount` command outputs, you may need to modify the code above.

Comment: instead of `> /dev/null` you can do `grep -q`

Comment: On my imac (macos 10.13.6), it only works without ```> /dev/null``` or ```-q```...

Comment: For me, this did not work as expected if you are chrooted because `mount` prepends the path to the chroot directory in the output but the argument given to `mountpoint` will not have that directory prepended. A dirty solution would be to remove the `on ` prefix in the grep search string.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use in my shell scripts on OS X 10.7.5

```
df | awk '{print $6}' | grep -Ex "/Volumes/myvolume"
```

For OS X 10.10 Yosemite I have to change to:

```
df | awk '{print $9}' | grep -Ex "/Volumes/myvolume"
```

Comment: Since it's the last field on the line that awk finds in both cases, you can use `$NF` instead of `$6` or `$9`.

Comment: Good answer! As a minor niggle, I'd probably use `awk` for the match instead of `grep`, but the idea of parsing `df` is **key**. I wonder if this is reliable under all circumstances?  On Catalina, `$9` is still the correct column (`Mounted on`), so a string match should do it?? I was hoping for something more like `findmnt` in Linux, but that's just not available in this post-ro filesystem world of mac os?

Answer (score 0):

For me from this solution in [stackoverflow_QA_Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script#answer-16093972)

```
[ -d /Volumes/ ] && echo "Already mounted /Volumes/ in OS X" || echo "Not mounted"
```

to use that

```
# 2 lines
$LOCALMOUNTPOINT="/folder/share" ;
[ -d $LOCALMOUNTPOINT ] && echo "Already mounted $LOCALMOUNTPOINT in OS X" || /sbin/mount -t smbfs //user:password@serveraddress/share $LOCALMOUNTPOINT
```

Here is [Stackoverflow_QA_how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line)
additional link about smb which I don't know well

```
# Here is my solution
$LOCALMOUNTPOINT="/folder/share" ;
[ ! -d $LOCALMOUNTPOINT ] && mkdir $LOCALMOUNTPOINT && /sbin/mount -t smbfs //user:password@serveraddress/share $LOCALMOUNTPOINT || echo already mounted $LOCALMOUNTPOINT
```

I have to make new folder for my SMOOTH use before mounting that.

so I added `mkdir $LOCALMOUNTPOINT`

Thank you I learned a lot with this case.
Have A nice day!!! ;)