# Unix command that checks for the existence of a file on another server?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am reading a list of file names from a config file. using a for loop im selecting each file in the list and then want to search for the file on a remote server.

```
for file in config
do

**search for file at {remoteserver}**
    returnStatus=$?
    if [ returnStatus = 0 ]; then
         email that file was found.
    fi
done
```

the search for file at the remote server is the part troubling me. Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Have you checked this question? [How to check if a directory exists in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59838/1983854). Do that together with `ssh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
for file in "${config[@]}"
do
    ssh user@remotehost test -e "$file"
    returnStatus=$?
    if [ $returnStatus -eq 0 ]; then
         email that file was found.
    fi
done
```

Comment: I get: "return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script".

Comment: @TomFenech I meant to write `exit` not return. Fixed.

Comment: The whole script now exits on the first iteration, so this doesn't work either.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for reporting feedback. Can you please ellaborate - the script exits on first iteration?

Comment: When you are calling `exit`, that exits the whole script running on the local machine, not just the `ssh` part of the script. So the whole script will `exit 0` or `exit -1` on the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

1. All the files are on separate servers
2. You want to send the email from your local system

this could be the solution:

```
for file in "${config[@]}"
do
    exists=$(ssh user@host "if [ -e \"$file\" ]; then echo '1'; else echo '0'; fi")
    if [ $exists = "1" ]
    then
        echo "$file exists"
        #send email
    fi
done
```

If all the files were on the same remote server, it would make more sense to do the loop within the `ssh` connection, rather than reconnecting every time.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for helping in debug the script and getting it fixed. As you can tell, I am not that great with `bash`. Hopefully will get there soon. Appreciate it. +1