# Check if a directory exists and is accessible

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

I want to check if a directory exists and it has access rights; if it does, then perform the tasks. This is the code I wrote, which might not have proper syntax.

Can you help me to correct it?

```
dir_test=/data/abc/xyz
if (test -d $dir_test & test –x $dir_test -eq 0);
 then
cd $dir_test
fi
```

I believe this can also be written like this.

```
dir_test=/data/abc/xyz
test -d $dir_test
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
test –x $dir_test
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
cd $dir_test
fi
fi
```

How can we write this more efficiently?

Comment: Because `[` ... `]` is a synonym for `test` this classifies as a **useless use of `test`** ;-)  See @chepner for the explanation.

Comment: More examples and explanation here: [How to check if a directory exists in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way to write the original `test`-based solution would be

```
if test -d "$dir_test" && test –x "$dir_test";
then
    cd $dir_test
fi
```

although what will you do if the test fails and you *don't* change directories? The remainder of the script will probably not work as expected.

You can shorten this by using the `[` synonym for `test`:

```
if [ -d "$dir_test" ] && [ -x "$dir_test" ]; then
```

or you can use the conditional command provided by `bash`:

```
if [[ -d "$dir_test" && -x "$dir_test" ]]; then
```

The best solution, since you are going to change directories if the tests succeed, is to simply *try* it, and abort if it fails:

```
cd "$dir_test" || {
  # Take the appropriate action; one option is to just exit with
  # an error.
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: THe only part I did not understand was if i use the statement cd "$dir_test || {exit1}" will it evaluate if the directory exists and accesible ?

Comment: Nothing following the `||` is evaluated if the `cd` succeeds.

Comment: Alternative: `(cd  "$dir_test" || exit;  ...)`. Use @chepner's example if you change any variables and they need to persist.

Answer (score 1):

```
dir_test=/data/abc/xyz
if (test -d $dir_test & test –x $dir_test -eq 0); # This is wrong. The `-eq 0` part will result in `test: too many arguments`. The subshell (parens) is also unnecessary and expensive.
 then
cd $dir_test
fi
```

`cd` can tell you if a directory is accessible. Just do

```
cd "$dir_test" || exit 1;
```

Even if you do decide to use `test` first, for some reason, you should *still* check the exit status of `cd`, lest you have a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -d $dir_test -a -x $dir_test ]
```

alternatively if you have /usr/bin/cd:

```
if [ /usr/bin/cd $dir_test ]
```

Comment: The POSIX standard recommends `[ -d $dir_test ] && [ -x $dir_test ]` in place of the `-a` operator.