# docker container volumes from directory access in CMD instruction

Tags: docker, coreos

docker container volumes from directory access in CMD instruction

`$ sudo docker run -d --name ext -v /external busybox /bin/sh`

and

## run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f "/external" ]]
then
    echo 'success!'
else
    echo 'Sorry, I can't find /external...'
fi
```

and

## Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER newbie

ADD run.sh /run.sh

RUN chmod +x /run.sh

CMD ["bash", "/run.sh"]
```

and

`$ sudo docker build -t app .`

and

`$ sudo docker run -d --volumes-from ext app
ac57afb95f923eeffd28e7d9d9cb76cb1b7699ebd`

So

`$ sudo docker logs ac57afb95f923eeffd28e7d9d9cb76cb1b7699ebd
Sorry, I can't find /external...`

My question is,

How can I access `/external` directory in `run.sh` in `CMD` instruction

impossible?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your `run.sh`

`-f` is check for file exists. in this case use `-d` check for directory exists.

[Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)

futhermore if you want make only volume container, need not add `-d`, `/bin/sh`
volume container run command change like this

`$ sudo docker run --name ext -v /external busybox`