# Bash Script - Wrapping Variables in Quotes

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I was doing some reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script/67458#67458) and it suggested that I wrap my variables in quotes just in case the value contains spaces.

If I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function checkDirectory()
{
    local checkDir=$1

    if [[ -d $checkDir ]] ; then 
        echo "File is directory"
    fi


}


checkDirectory "/home/someuser/Downloads/"
```

If I wrap my parameter, in this case, `"/home/someuser/Downloads/"` in quotes, do I still need to wrap $1 and checkDir in quotes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't have to as `$1` will be assigned to `checkDir` correctly and bash's `[[ ]]` won't do word splitting and your script will work as expected.

However, in case if you use `sh` test `[ .. ]` then you'll have a problem with:

```
if [ -d $checkDir ] ; then 
    echo "File is directory"
fi
```

So it's always good practice to quote your variables rather than having to remember it matters and when not.

Comment: The right side of an assignment and *some* places in `[[ ]]` are about the only places its safe to leave the quotes off. Much simpler to just always use quotes than to keep track of where it's safe to omit them.