# Test if directory exists or not

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, gnu

Here is my code, and it works but it always says that directory exist, doesnt matter what I write. Moreover it does not print a variable in `echo $DIRECTORY`. What I need to fix?

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d $DIRECTORY ]; then
echo "Directory exists"
elif [ ! -d $DIRECTORY ]; then
echo "Directory does not exists"
fi
echo $DIRECTORY
```

Comment: Did you assign the DIRECTORY variable beforehand? Like `DIRECTORY=/etc`

Comment: I just write ./program(it's a name of program) abc(it's a name of directory, which does not exist)

Comment: Then substitute `$DIRECTORY` for `$1` (the first argument to the script)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a directory exists in a Bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-can-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Passing variables to shell script

- You have to instruct you script that *DIRECTORY* is *a variable*, passed as first script argument.
- You have to enclose your variable into **double-quotes** in order to ensure spaces and special characters, like empty variables, to be correctly parsed.

Sample:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIRECTORY="$1"

if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    echo "Directory '$DIRECTORY' exists"
else
    echo "Directory '$DIRECTORY' does not exists"
fi
echo "$DIRECTORY"
```

Other sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY="$1"
FILE="$2"
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    if [ -e "$DIRECTORY/$FILE" ]; then
        printf 'File "%s" found in "%s":\n  ' "$FILE" "$DIRECTORY"
        /bin/ls -ld "$DIRECTORY/$FILE"
    else
        echo "Directory '$DIRECTORY' exists, but no '$FILE'!"
    fi
else
    echo "Directory '$DIRECTORY' does not exists!"
fi
echo "$DIRECTORY/$FILE"
```

Comment: Right @gniourf_gniourf! :->>

Comment: Yes, but @gniourf_gniourf is right! Usig `elif` there reflect a stupid 3 way boolean logic!