# bash if-statement check for file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, conditional-statements

I know how to check for a file in bash using this code

```
file=$1

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
...
fi
```

But I want to do something when it's not a file.

```
file=$3

if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ "$2" == "" ] || [ $file is not a file??? ]
then 
echo "use: notEmpty notEmpty file"
fi
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a directory exists in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ "$2" == "" ] || [ ! -f "$file" ]
```

The whitespaces after `[` and before `]` are important.

Comment: Ok thank you but ny actual question was how to do the $file is not a file part?

Comment: The `!` preceding `-f` negates the test, so the last `[` command succeeds if `$file` is *not* a file.