# Scantailor CLI output

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, scanning, post-processing

I am working with `scantailor-cli` and I can't get any output images, only the creation of the project with the input images and also without respecting the configuration.

[The sample bash script is](https://gist.github.com/NikaZhenya/2489089097969954e7e3bf36ae7d6a35):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Este script requiere: xsane, perl-rename, Scan Tailor

impresora="hpaio:/usb/Deskjet_F4400_series?serial=CN01BC111V05C5" # Nombre de la impresora: usar scanimage -L para ver los dispositivos disponibles
dpi=150 # DPI a usar
directorio_padre="scan" # Nombre de la carpeta donde se creará todo
nombre_proyecto="proyecto" # Nombre del proyecto de Scan Tailor
orientacion=left # Orientación para rotar las hojas en Scan Tailor; posibles: left, right, upsidedown y none
plantilla=2 # Tipo de proyecto en Scan Tailor; posibles: 0 (automático), 1 (una sola página), 1.5 (página y media) y 2 (dos páginas)
contenido=normal # Tipo de detención del contenido en Scan Tailor; posibles: cautious, normal y aggressive
margenes=10 # Cantidad de margen que se agregará en todos los lados en Scan Tailor
alineacion_vertical=center # Alienación vertical de los contenidos en Scant Tailor; posibles: top, center y bottom
alineacion_horizontal=center # Alienación horizontal de los contenidos en Scant Tailor; posibles: left, center y right

# Para obtener la ruta absoluta del repositorio; viene de http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-which-directory-it-is-stored-in
SCRIPT_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}";
if ([ -h "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]) then
    while([ -h "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]) do SCRIPT_PATH=`readlink "${SCRIPT_PATH}"`; done
fi
pushd . > /dev/null
cd `dirname ${SCRIPT_PATH}` > /dev/null
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`;
popd  > /dev/null

# Va a la carpeta donde está el script
echo "Yendo a «$SCRIPT_PATH»."
cd $SCRIPT_PATH

# Busca si ya existe un directorio con el nombre a utilizar; viene de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script
if [ -d "$directorio_padre" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Ya existe el directorio con nombre «$directorio_padre»."
    exit
fi

# Indica si se mencionó un número entero; viene de https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151654/checking-if-an-input-number-is-an-integer
if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Un número entero es necesario para el número de páginas a escanear."
    exit
fi

# Escaner con xsane
echo "Iniciando escaneando en nueva carpeta llamada «$directorio_padre»..."
mkdir $directorio_padre && cd $directorio_padre
mkdir originales && cd originales
echo "Escaneando portada a color..."
scanimage -d $impresora -v -p --resolution $dpi --format tiff > out0.tif
echo "Escaneando interiores en grises..."
scanimage -d $impresora -v -p --resolution $dpi --format tiff --mode Gray --batch --batch-start=1 --batch-count=$1

# Cambio de nombres con perl-rename
echo "Cambiando nombres de los archivos..."
perl-rename -v "s/out(\d\d\.tif)/p_0\1/" *.tif
perl-rename -v "s/out(\d\.tif)/p_00\1/" *.tif

# Postprocesamiento con Scan Tailor
cd ..
scantailor-cli -v --orientation=$orientacion --layout=$plantilla --deskew=auto --content-detection=$contenido --margins=$margenes --alignment-vertical=$alineacion_vertical --alignment-horizontal=$alineacion_horizontal --output-dpi=$dpi -o=$SCRIPT_PATH/$directorio_padre/$nombre_proyecto.ScanTailor $SCRIPT_PATH/$directorio_padre/originales $SCRIPT_PATH/$directorio_padre/scan-tailor
```

The Scan Tailor command in this script is: `scantailor-cli -v --orientation=left --layout=2 --deskew=auto --content-detection=normal --margins=10 --alignment-vertical=center --alignment-horizontal=center --output-dpi=150 -o=path/to/proyecto.ScanTailor path/to/originales path/to/scan-tailor`.

Is it possible to execute all the workflow with the cli interface?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. As far as I understand the logic, this is currently (version 0.9.12.2-1, Arch community repo) a bug in the program (I now filed it [here](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/issues/292)).

These are the steps called "filters":

1. Fix Orientation
2. Split Pages
3. Deskew
4. Select Content
5. Margins
6. Output

The default range claims to be `4..6` according to `scantailor-cli -h` but it really is `1..4` what you can see via `-v`. Hence you need to set `--start-filter=4 --end-filter=6`.

Comment: I am seeing the issue at GitHub, and I also have that version from Arch Linux repo. So by default it is not doing margins and output, and that is why I have no output; so if I want all the filters I need `--start-filter=1 --end-filter=6`, right?

Comment: As far as I understand it, yes.