# what does exclamation mark mean in linux?

Tags: bash, terminal, git-bash

I have been going through some online courses on that they asked me to clone a repository from GitHub as follows...

***Clone the git repository that contains the artifacts needed for this lab, if it doesn't already exist.***

```
[ ! -d 'cc201' ] && git clone https://gitlab.com/ibm/skills-network/courses/cc201.git
```

But, I don't understand the below command

```
[ ! -d 'cc201' ]
```

what's the use of this?? Can anyone know what exactly does it used for!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a directory exists in a Bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-can-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `!` does not have a special meaning in **Linux** (the operating system), but in several standard programs in Linux. In your case it is not so much a feature of bash (as Mark Bramnik claimed in his otherwise correct answer), but of the standard program called `test` or `[`. Since bash emulates this command internally, of course it has to interpret the `!` as well, but the definition can be found by doing a *man test*, where it is described as:

> ```
>    ! EXPRESSION
>          EXPRESSION is false
> ```

Actually, bash **does** have a `!` too, with a related, but not identical meaning. If you invoke a program by prefix it with `!`, i.e.

```
! prog
```

bash sets the exit code to 0 if *prog* terminated with a non-zero exit code, and sets it to 1 if *prog* terminated with exit code zero. Therefore, you could have written

```
[ ! -d cc201 ]
```

equally well as

```
! [ -d cc201 ]
```

The overall effect is the same, but the former is the `!` from *test*, which in turn in emulated by bash, while the latter is the builtin ststus-code negator of bash.

Answer (score 3):

Exclamation mark is for "Not" (like in boolean), `-d` flag is for folder exists in bash.

So its essentially a condition, that says: "if the folder named 'cc201' does not exist then do something

Comment: It's not in the question by it may be worth mentioning for someone else reading this that `&&` does short-circuit evaluation, so the condition to the left must be true for the condition to the right to be evaluated.